# Sorting JSON Output in PHP

Tags: php, arrays, json, sorting

I've got the following JSON:

```
{
"row":  [
    {
    "sort":3,
    "type":"fat",
    "widgets":
        [
            {"values": [3,9] },
            {"values": [8,4] }                  
        ]
    },
{
    "sort":2,
    "type":"three",
    "widgets":
    [
        {"values": [3,4] },
        {"values": [12,7] },
        {"values": [12,7] }                         
    ]
}                       
]
}
```

And this PHP to output it:

```
foreach ( $value->row as $therow )
{
    echo "<div class='row ".$therow->type."'>";

    foreach ( $therow->widgets as $thewidgets )
    {
        echo "<div class='widget'>";
        echo $thewidgets->values[0];
        echo "</div>";

    }

    echo "</div>";

}
```

What I would like to do is sort the ouput based on the sort value in the JSON, any ideas?

Comment: And what kind of sort would be “2” or “3”?

Comment: The order of the row as it was created in the backend

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use [usort](http://au.php.net/usort):

```
function my_sort($a, $b)
{
    if ($a->sort < $b->sort) {
        return -1;
    } else if ($a->sort > $b->sort) {
        return 1;
    } else {
        return 0;
    }
}

usort($value->row, 'my_sort');
```

Answer (score 2):

See here:

[Sorting an associative array in PHP](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/777597/sorting-an-associative-array-in-php/777625)

for user-defined sorting.

Answer (score 0):

See following if you want to do it on client side.

[Sorting JSON by values](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/881510/json-sorting-question/881987#881987)

Answer (score 0):

Just sort the data before printing it in the second `foreach` loop:

```
foreach ($value->row as $therow) {
    if ($therow->sort == 2) {
        // sort $therow->widgets according to whatever sort 2 means
    } elseif ($therow->sort == 3) {
        // sort $therow->widgets according to whatever sort 3 means
    }
    echo "<div class='row ".$therow->type."'>";
    foreach ($therow->widgets as $thewidgets) {
        echo "<div class='widget'>";
        echo $thewidgets->values[0];
        echo "</div>";
    }
    echo "</div>";
}
```