# PHP array multidimensional sorting

Tags: php, sorting, multidimensional-array

I have a multi-dimensional array like so.

```
[0] => Array
    (
        [time] => 1312206805
        [item] => email@example.net created ad ad.
    )

[1] => Array
    (
        [time] => 1312206805
        [item] => email@example.net created an ad.
    )

[2] => Array
    (
        [time] => 1312130982
        [item] => info@example.org created an ad.
    )
```

I'd like to sort by the time, while maintaining indexes and keeping each parent array together.

Comment: Please check your older questions and accepted correct answers. Community helps you. Why you don't help community ?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Sorting a multidimensional array in PHP?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1795244/sorting-a-multidimensional-array-in-php) ... or one of other dozens like it on SO... just use `uasort`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
uasort($arr,function($a,$b){
    return $a['time'] - $b['time'];
});
```

Requires php5.3+
If you use older version you can replace anonymous function by other callback

Comment: Thanks! This worked great. Just what I needed. Saved me a few hours of guess and check. :)

Comment: it is great chance to use advice in my comment to your question