# PHP sorting according sub array

Tags: php

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Sorting a multidimensional array in PHP?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1795244/sorting-a-multidimensional-array-in-php)

```
   $songs =  array(
    '1' => array('artist'=>'The Smashing Pumpkins', 'songname'=>'Soma'),
    '2' => array('artist'=>'The Decemberists', 'songname'=>'The Island'),
    '3' => array('artist'=>'Fleetwood Mac', 'songname' =>'Second-hand News')
);
```

Answer should come like this:

```
   Array(
[0] => Array
    (
        [artist] => Fleetwood Mac
        [song] => Second-hand News
    )

[1] => Array
    (
        [artist] => The Decemberists
        [song] => The Island
    )

[2] => Array
    (
        [artist] => The Smashing Pumpkins
        [song] => Cherub Rock
    )
)
```

Please help me on this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I know php

Try This :

```
 function subval_sort($a,$subkey) {
foreach($a as $k=>$v) {
    $b[$k] = strtolower($v[$subkey]);
}
asort($b);
foreach($b as $key=>$val) {
    $c[] = $a[$key];
}
return $c;
 }
```

call to

```
 $songs = subval_sort($songs,'artist'); 
 print_r($songs);
```

Comment: "I know php" - http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=EmEPXXJ4sKw ;-)