# PHP Multi Dimension Array Sorting

Tags: php, arrays

I have the following array setup called `$players`:

```
Array(
    [4153234567] => Array(
        [name] => JohnnyAppleSeed
        [rating] => 00
    )
    [4807173711] => Array(
        [name] => admin
        [rating] => 6000
    )
    [4801234562] => Array(
        [name] => 4801234562
        [rating] = > 00
    )
)
```

I need to sort this array and echo:

```
$name of person with highest rating
$name of person with lowest rating
```

then remove these people from the array im looking at and repeat till I have moved through everyone.

Any ideas?

Comment: Possible duplicate [Sorting a multidimensional array in PHP?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1795244/sorting-a-multidimensional-array-in-php).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try `usort`

```
 usort($players, "player_sort");

 function player_sort($a,$b) {
      return $a['rating']>$b['rating'];
 }
```

http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.usort.php

Once sorted, you can take the first and last element to get the highest and lowest.

Comment: Man, beat me to it because I took the time to format his code first :)

Comment: Thank you! :D Arrays confuse me!

Answer (score 0):

Given the data you provided, you're actually going to need to use uasort -- that is unless the keys of the array (ie.4153234567) don't matter to you.  Otherwise the principle and sorting routine is the same.

Also to remove items you would use unset().  If you save the keys in to $first, $last, then

```
unset($players[$first]);
unset($players[$last]);
```