# Sorting a multidimensional array for ranking using PHP in CodeIgniter?

Tags: php, codeigniter, ranking, sorting

I'm looking to use the results in an array and sort them using a ranking algorithm similar to say Hacker News or Reddit.

[For example, paraphrasing the HN algorithm](http://amix.dk/blog/post/19574):
    Score = P / (T+2)^G

```
where,
P = points of an item (e.g. votes + comments + likes)
T = time since submission (in hours)
G = Gravity, (on HN defaults to 1.8)
```

From what I understand, I need to use a PHP sorting array, but the PHP manual is confusing, and the similar answers on StackOverflow have very specific answers without many comments as to what the function is doing. e.g. [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/96759/how-do-i-sort-a-multidimensional-array-in-php), [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2699086/php-sort-multidimensional-array-by-value) & [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1795244/sorting-a-multidimensional-array-in-php).

My data looks as follows

```
Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [post_created] => 2011-12-12 07:18:17
            [post_num_likes] => 1
            [post_num_comments] => 0
            [post_message] => Some message
            [votes] => 16
        )

    [1] => Array
        (
            [post_created] => 2011-12-11 22:17:16
            [post_num_likes] => 0
            [post_num_comments] => 4
            [post_message] => Another message
            [votes] => 21
        )

    [2] => Array
        (
            [post_created] => 2011-12-11 20:21:11
            [post_num_likes] => 1
            [post_num_comments] => 2
            [post_message] => Next message
            [votes] => 1
        )

    [3] => Array
        (
            [post_created] => 2011-12-11 20:11:47
            [post_num_likes] => 0
            [post_num_comments] => 0
            [post_message] => Something else
            [votes] => 0
        )

    [4] => Array
        (
            [post_created] => 2011-12-11 20:09:46
            [post_num_likes] => 1
            [post_num_comments] => 0
            [post_message] => Another message 
            [votes] => 5
        )
```

So far as I understand, I need to do something like the following:

```
// Send array as 2nd parameter due to way you call functions in CodeIgniter
uksort($array, array('Class_name','postrank'));

function postrank($a, $b) {
    // some sorting function here
    return strcmp($a, $b);
}
```

I've tried copying and pasting various functions, but as they're not so well commented, it's hard to know what's going on.

How might I go about recreating a similar post ranking sorting function with the above data?

Comment: You need to be more specific about your ranking criterium

Comment: Hm, how so? It's `(votes + comments + likes) / (created_time + 2) ^G`

Comment: so are you wanting us to come up with the algorithm, write it, and write the sorting for you?

Comment: No, I was hoping I could provide enough information of where my understanding is currently so that someone might suggest how I might go from here. As I mention, there are several similar questions, but the answers are esoteric and presume a level of understanding about PHP sorting arrays in the first place - I have none. Please don't assume the worst about me, I'm lost and hoped if I provide detailed information, links and what I'd already read up on, it might help this novice developer.

Comment: There is nothing esoteric about comparing 2 values

Answer (score 2, accepted):

amidoinitrite?

```
SELECT * , (
votes + post_num_comments + post_num_likes - 1
) / POW( ROUND( (
TIME_TO_SEC( TIMEDIFF( NOW( ) , post_created ) ) / 3600 ) + 2 ) , 1.8
) AS score
FROM hacker_news
ORDER BY score DESC
```

[image]

The formula on website is actually: **Score = (P-1) / (T+2) ^ G**

Comment: This is actually very good. I honestly wasn't aware you do such a thing with an SQL query, so I'm impressed - thank you.

Comment: @Joe, everything you can do in SQL, **do it**! :) It is almost in all cases lot faster than sorting/calulating in PHP etc. I'm pretty sure HN does it in SQL.

Comment: I appreciate it. When you use 'score' as an alias, is that value generated then accessible in the resulting array?

Comment: @Joe, yes of course, like `$row['score']`, WYSIWYG on screenshot.

Answer (score 2):

My example code for PHP older than 5.3 :)

```
<?php
function customSort($a, $b){
    foreach(array('a', 'b') as $vn){
        $tmp = $$vn;
        $p = $tmp['post_num_likes'] + $tmp['post_num_comments'] + $tmp['votes'];
        $t = ceil((time() - strtotime($tmp['post_created'])) / 3600);
        $$vn = $p / pow($t + 2, 1.81);
    }
    return $a - $b;
}
usort($array, 'customSort');

var_dump($array);
```

Answer (score 1):

```
$score = function($arr) {
    extract($arr);
    return ($votes + $comments + $likes) / pow($created_time + 2, 1.8);
};

usort($array, function($a, $b) use ($score) {
    return $score($a) - $score($b);
});
```

This needs php 5.3 because I used anonymous functions.