# PHP sort multidimensional with more than 1 colum to sort by

Tags: php, arrays, parsing, sorting, multidimensional-array

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How do I sort a multidimensional array in php](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/96759/how-do-i-sort-a-multidimensional-array-in-php)
>   [Sorting a multidimensional array in PHP?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1795244/sorting-a-multidimensional-array-in-php)

How can I sort an array (see below) by high, medium, low?

```
# Generate random events
$severity = array('high','medium','low');
$events = array();
for ($i=1,$n=10;$i<=$n;$i++) {
        $events["Country{$i}"] = array(
                'high'          =>              rand(0,100),
                'medium'        =>              rand(0,100),
                'low'           =>              rand(0,100),
                'total'         =>              'X'
        );
}
```

I means that in the bottom line i'll have a sorted array which holds all the `countryX` sorted by the highest value of high, then medium, and then low - all in 1 big array.

tried different approaches but faild to get the correct result.

Comment: read the documentation on [array_multisort](http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-multisort.php)

Comment: found a solution based on array_multisort documentation, available on http://pastebin.com/taMH4Qni

Answer (score 0):

```
function sillySort($a, $b) {
    if ($a['high'] > $b['high']) {
         return -1;
    } else if ($a['high'] < $b['high']) {
         return 1;
    } else {
        if ($a['medium'] > $b['medium']) {
            return -1;
        } else if ($a['medium'] < $b['medium']) {
            return 1;
        } else {
            if ($a['low'] > $b['low']) {
                return -1;
            } else if ($a['low'] < $b['low']) {
                return 1;
            } else {
                return 0;
            }
        }
    }
}

uksort($events, 'sillySort');
```

Comment: not working, $events is a multi-dimensional array and it cant read the values in uksort.

Comment: found a solution based on array_multisort documentation, available on http://pastebin.com/taMH4Qni

Comment: I tested this with your code and it did work....