# php array sorting in order

Tags: php, arrays, sorting

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Sorting an associative array in PHP](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/777597/sorting-an-associative-array-in-php)
>   [Sorting a multidimensional array in PHP?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1795244/sorting-a-multidimensional-array-in-php)

I have a system which allows orders to be allocated to a delivery driver.The following source brings up a list of current available distributors, and the distance they are away from the customer:

```
$franchise_a_status = array();
  $franchise_a_status[] = array('id' => '', 'text' => 'Please Select');
  $franchise_query = mysql_query("select franchise_id, franchise_surname, franchise_firstname, franchise_postcode, franchise_availability  from " . TABLE_FRANCHISE . " where franchise_availability=1");
    $origin = $cInfo->entry_postcode;
  while ($franchise = mysql_fetch_array($franchise_query)) {
    $destination = $franchise['franchise_postcode'];
    $json = file_get_contents("http://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/distancematrix/json?origins=$origin&destinations=$destination&mode=driving&sensor=false&units=imperial");
    $result = json_decode($json, true);
    $distance = $result['rows'][0]['elements'][0]['distance']['text'];


    $franchise_a_status[] = array('id' => $franchise['franchise_id'],
                                'text' => $franchise['franchise_surname']. ' ' .$franchise['franchise_firstname'].' '.'('.$distance.')');
                 }
```

the list is shown using a drop down menu:

```
    array('text' => tep_draw_pull_down_menu('franchise_id',$franchise_a_status));
```

I need the array to be sorted in order of the shortest distance to the highest distance.

Comment: How about sorting them using MySQL instead?

Comment: Look into using `usort`. [PHP Documentation of `usort`](http://au.php.net/manual/en/function.usort.php)

Answer (score 0):

1. Add the distance to `$franchise_a_status`.
2. Sort according to distance ([usort](http://php.net/usort)).
3. Create a new array without the distance value ([array_map](http://php.net/array_map) or [foreach](http://php.net/foreach)).

Comment: Can u expand on this a bit more please. the $distance is included in the $franchise_a_status array.

Comment: I think it's best to include it as its own value, with its own key.