# Sort multi-dimensional array by specific key

Tags: php, sorting, object, multidimensional-array

I have an array:

```
Array (
    [0] => stdClass Object (
        [user_id] => 1
        [ID] => 1
        [user_login] => admin
        [display_name] => admin
        [user_email] => webbinformation@nacka.se
        [meta_value] => a:1:{s:13:\"administrator\";s:1:\"1\";}
    )
    [1] => stdClass Object (
        [user_id] => 4
        [ID] => 4
        [user_login] => ungtinflytande
        [display_name] => ungtinflytande
        [user_email] => klarakviberg@gmail.com
        [meta_value] => a:1:{s:13:\"administrator\";s:1:\"1\";}
    )
    [2] => stdClass Object (
        [user_id] => 5
        [ID] => 5
        [user_login] => inflytandepilot
        [display_name] => inflytandepilot
        [user_email] => hildalundgren@hotmail.com
        [meta_value] => a:1:{s:6:\"author\";s:1:\"1\";}
    )
    [3] => stdClass Object (
        [user_id] => 11
        [ID] => 11
        [user_login] => matsbohman
        [display_name] => matsbohman
        [user_email] => mats.bohman@nacka.se
        [meta_value] => a:1:{s:6:\"editor\";s:1:\"1\";}
    )
    [4] => stdClass Object (
        [user_id] => 12
        [ID] => 12
        [user_login] => klarakviberg
        [display_name] => klarakviberg
        [user_email] => nastasteg@nacka.se
        [meta_value] => a:1:{s:13:\"administrator\";s:1:\"1\";}
    )
)
```

...that I wanna sort by the `display_name` key. I currently print it like this:

```
foreach ($blogusers as $bloguser) {
    ...
}
```

How do I do this?

Answer (score 47, accepted):

You would use usort() - http://php.net/usort

My suggestion would be:

```
    function cmp($a, $b)
    {
        return strcmp($a->display_name, $b->display_name);
    }

    usort($blogusers, "cmp");

    foreach ($blogusers as $bloguser)
    {
        ...
```

Comment: usort() is the way to go for sure.  Is strcmp the right function if one were to want to sort on, say, a float?  My guess would be separate comparators functions depending on type might be a good idea...

Answer (score 17):

See usort: http://php.net/manual/en/function.usort.php

```
usort($array, "my_cmp");

function my_cmp($a, $b) {
  if ($a->display_name == $b->display_name) {
    return 0;
  }
  return ($a->display_name < $b->display_name) ? -1 : 1;
}
```

Answer (score 10):

I have find answer at https://joshtronic.com/2013/09/23/sorting-associative-array-specific-key/

```
function sortBy($field, &$array, $direction = 'asc')
{
    usort($array, create_function('$a, $b', '
        $a = $a["' . $field . '"];
        $b = $b["' . $field . '"];

        if ($a == $b)
        {
            return 0;
        }

        return ($a ' . ($direction == 'desc' ? '>' : '<') .' $b) ? -1 : 1;
    '));

    return true;
}
```

And now call this function by specific array key.

```
$newArray = sortBy('display_name',   $blogusers);
```

And if sort in asc/desc just add one argument,

```
sortBy('display_name',   $blogusers, 'desc');
```

Comment: create_function is deprecated in php 7.2.0

Answer (score 4):

A simpler way would be ...

```
$key = array_column($blogusers, 'display_name');
array_multisort($key, SORT_ASC, $blogusers]

foreach ($blogusers as $bloguser) ...
```

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/72835614/2943403

Comment: This is the correct and the best method, because `array_multisort()` also allows you to sort by multiple indexes.

Answer (score 0):

Your array looks like the result of a database query. If this is a case, let the database do the sorting: just append `ORDER BY display_name` to the query.

Answer (score -1):

Take a look at following article. It does describe how to use `usort()` and also describes how to use `create_function()` so that you can use single function to sort on different fields (with required direction `asc` or `desc`).

http://phpave.com/sorting-associative-array-specific-key/

Answer (score -1):

In case you are stuck with error or your array doesn't sort you can give this a try as this works for me-

```
usort($blogusers,function ($a, $b)
{
    return strcmp($a["display_name"], $b["display_name"]);
});
```

Comment: That is not how you access object properties.