# Magento: Sort items of Varien Data Collection

Tags: magento

I would like to sort a Varien_Object in Magento with a custom attribute.
I got something like this:

```
$thing_1 = new Varien_Object();
$thing_1->setName('Richard');
$thing_1->setOrder(2);

$thing_2 = new Varien_Object();
$thing_2->setName('Jane');
$thing_2->setOrder(1);

$collection_of_things = new Varien_Data_Collection();
$collection_of_things
    ->addItem($thing_1)
    ->addItem($thing_2);
```

I want to sort it ASC so that `Jane` can be in front of `Richard`

Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Varien_Data_Collection has method for sorting but this method is rendered to SQL query in the execution.

```
public function setOrder($field, $direction = self::SORT_ORDER_DESC)
```

if you additems manually it will be added with index in the order you added them so what you need to do it to sort the objects first then add them to the data collection

look at this question [Sort array of objects by object fields](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4282413/php-sort-array-of-objects-by-object-fields)

Comment: Ok thanks for the reply. I wanted to avoid doing this but seems I got no choices.