# PHP sort multidimensional objects by property value

Tags: php

After hours of research i decided to ask this question, bcoz no solution found so far.
I need to sort multidimensional objects by property value, objects are results of json_decode() of a multidimensional json, so i need to sort following objects by `order` property:

```
    stdClass Object
(
    [main] => stdClass Object
        (
            [order] => 1
            [size] => 100
            [child] => stdClass Object
                (
                    [c1] => stdClass Object
                        (
                            [order] => 2 // must be second item
                            [size] => 100
                            [child] => stdClass Object
                                (
                                    [d1] => stdClass Object
                                        (
                                            [order] => 1
                                            [size] => 100
                                        )
                                )
                        )
                    [c2] => stdClass Object
                        (
                            [order] => 1, // must be first item
                            [size] => 100,
                            [child] => stdClass Object
                                (
                                    [d2] => stdClass Object
                                        (
                                            [order] => 1
                                            [size] => 100
                                        )
                                )                           
                        )
```

Thank you!

Comment: Try http://stackoverflow.com/q/4282413/1513471

Comment: There is an array of objects, it's not my case.

Comment: @innowww If you wish these to be in a particular order, you will need to convert it into an array of objects.