# Wordpress Terms natsort

Tags: wordpress, sorting, taxonomy

I want to alphanumeric sort the terms obtained from a custom taxanomy..

```
My data is appearing as 
1 pack
10 pack
11 pack
12 pack
2 pack
20 pack
I want the term to be sorted alphanumeric
1 pack
2 pack
10 pack
11 pack
12 pack
20 pack
```

As term is associative multidimensional  array how do I use the usort($term, "strnatcmp")..
I found this [example](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4282413/php-sort-array-of-objects-by-object-fields) but not performing alpha numeric sort

Comment: I am able to do this usort($packterms, function($a, $b) { return strnatcmp($a->name, $b->name); })

Answer (score 0):

You could add leading zeros with `zeroise`:

http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/zeroise

Comment: I am not asking to to pad zeros.. I need to do natsort.. And I have able to do so using usort