# PHP Sort Array By SubArray Value by the 3rd level

Tags: php

I have an array that needs to be sorted by the third level.

I need to order the array by the `fullname` value. Is this possible?

```
$array = array(
    'family1' => array(
        'family_data' => array(
            'fullname' => 'Samuel Smith',
            '...' => '...'
        )
    ),
    'family2' => array(
        'family_data' => array(
            'fullname' => 'John Doe',
            '...' => '...'
        )
    ),
    'family3' => array(
        'family_data' => array(
            'fullname' => 'Adrian Chan',
            '...' => '...'
        )
    )
);
```

Easier reading:

```
Array
(
    [family1] => Array
        (
            [family_data] => Array
                (
                    [fullname] => Samuel Smith
                    [...] => ...
                )

        )

    [family2] => Array
        (
            [family_data] => Array
                (
                    [fullname] => John Doe
                    [...] => ...
                )

        )

    [family3] => Array
        (
            [family_data] => Array
                (
                    [fullname] => Adrian Chan
                    [...] => ...
                )

        )

)
```

The desired result would be:

```
Array
(
    [family3] => Array
        (
            [family_data] => Array
                (
                    [fullname] => Adrian Chan
                    [...] => ...
                )

        )

    [family2] => Array
        (
            [family_data] => Array
                (
                    [fullname] => John Doe
                    [...] => ...
                )

        )

    [family1] => Array
        (
            [family_data] => Array
                (
                    [fullname] => Samuel Smith
                    [...] => ...
                )

        )

)
```

Comment: (The code before your recent edit would have been better, as we can copy-paste it into our editor to test. (Which I did.))

Comment: stackoverflow.com/questions/15062210/how-do-i-sort-the-follwing-array

Comment: @Dogbert Thanks, I'll remember that for next time

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use [`uasort`](http://php.net/uasort)

> uasort — Sort an array with a user-defined comparison function and maintain index association

```
uasort($array, function($a, $b) {
    return strcmp($a['family_data']['fullname'], $b['family_data']['fullname']);
});
```

Test:

```
$array = array(
    'family1' => array(
        'family_data' => array(
            'fullname' => 'Ben Smith',
            '...' => '...',
            '...' => '...'
        ),
        '...' => '...',
        '...' => '...'
    ),
    'family2' => array(
        'family_data' => array(
            'fullname' => 'John Doe',
            '...' => '...',
            '...' => '...'
        ),
        '...' => '...',
        '...' => '...'
    ),
    'family3' => array(
        'family_data' => array(
            'fullname' => 'Aen Smith',
            '...' => '...',
            '...' => '...'
        ),
        '...' => '...',
        '...' => '...'
    ),
);

uasort($array, function($a, $b) {
    return strcmp($a['family_data']['fullname'], $b['family_data']['fullname']);
});

print_r($array);
```

Output:

```
Array
(
    [family3] => Array
        (
            [family_data] => Array
                (
                    [fullname] => Aen Smith
                    [...] => ...
                )

            [...] => ...
        )

    [family1] => Array
        (
            [family_data] => Array
                (
                    [fullname] => Ben Smith
                    [...] => ...
                )

            [...] => ...
        )

    [family2] => Array
        (
            [family_data] => Array
                (
                    [fullname] => John Doe
                    [...] => ...
                )

            [...] => ...
        )

)
```

Comment: How would you changethe ordering, sorting by ASC or DESC?

Answer (score 1):

Try this :

```
$sort = array();
foreach($your_array as $k=>$v) {
    $sort['fullname'][$k] = $v['family_data']['fullname'];
}

array_multisort($sort['fullname'], SORT_ASC, $your_array);


echo "<pre>";
print_r($your_array);
```

Answer (score 0):

http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.array-multisort.php
Take a look at example 3, I think that would help you out.

Answer (score 0):

[Sort array of objects by object fields](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4282413/php-sort-array-of-objects-by-object-fields)
You can do that using the PHP `usort` function 
http://php.net/manual/en/function.usort.php