# How to order an array by inner array key value?

Tags: php

I have an array of arrays.  I want to order these arrays by their ['date'] field.  So the latest is at index [0].  How can I do this?

Here is an example of my `print_r`

```
$array=    (
    [0] => Array
        (
            [date] => 01/05/2013 12:00
            [location] => Town Hall
            [minutes] => mydomain.com
            [agenda] => 
        ),
 [1] => Array
        (
            [date] => 09/05/2013 12:00
            [location] => Town Hall
            [minutes] => mydomain.com/walker
            [agenda] => 
        )

)
```

Comment: you'll need http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.array-multisort.php

Comment: Also related and maybe easier to understand: [PHP, sort array of objects by object fields](http://stackoverflow.com/q/4282413/218196).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

just try this -

```
$array = array(
    0 => array('date'=>'01/05/2013 12:00', 'location'=>'A'),
    1 => array('date'=>'09/05/2013 12:00', 'location'=>'B'),
    2 => array('date'=>'03/05/2013 12:00', 'location'=>'C'),
    3 => array('date'=>'02/05/2013 12:00', 'location'=>'D')
);

echo '<pre>';
print_r($array);
echo '</pre>';

function sorting($a, $b){
    $a = strtotime($a['date']);
    $b = strtotime($b['date']);

    if ($a == $b) {
        return 0;
    }
    return ($a < $b) ? -1 : 1;
}

usort($array, "sorting");

echo '<pre>';
print_r($array);
echo '</pre>';
```

see live demo - http://codepad.org/biXJgHQA

Comment: :) my pleasure. You are most Nicola

Comment: Related question, would I be better storing it as a different format if I want to then check the first array date to see if it's in the future?

Comment: If you can sort it in first that will be better. Then you don't need to usort your array again. probably you are fetching your data from database. if so then write appropriate query for that. If not then you may need to use usort after getting full array

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
usort($array,function($a,$b){
    return strcmp($a['date'],$b['date']);
}
```

or if PHP < 5.3

```
function my_sort($a,$b){
    return strcmp($a['date'],$b['date']);
}
usort($array,'my_sort');
```

Comment: and what if php < 5.3 ?

Comment: `function my_sort($a,$b){ return strcmp($a['date'],$b['date']); } usort($array,'my_sort');`

Comment: @TimStamp better update the answer instead of putting it in comment.

Comment: `strcmp` on date fields doesn't sound like a good idea.

Comment: that's why `array_multisort` is a better approach.

Comment: If the dates are formatted like this, then `strcmp` won't work indeed. `20/01/2013` is "larger" than `01/02/2013`.

Comment: @Twisted1919: `array_multisort` is not a magic potion that will fix all your problems. It would not solve the date/time sorting problem here. And generally speaking, it offsets being slightly easier to use by being much more wasteful to boot.

Comment: @FelixKling Yes its doesn't seem to be working as the date is being returned like this

Comment: You'll have to format the date in UTC date format, or as a unix timestamp first.

Comment: whats a UTC date format?

Comment: @Tim: UTC is a time standard, not a format. The format ISO 8061 would do fine (http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ISO_8601).

Comment: It's a universal standard where the date is written as something similar to `YYYY-MM-DD HH-MM-SS +XXXX` - this also (usefully) makes it string sortable.

Comment: You're right I meant ISO 8601, but UTC is easier to remember ;)