# Get taxonomies in a category archive page

Tags: arrays, wordpress, taxonomy

I'd like to show all the taxonomies related to the posts in a category page (archive).

I've the following code

```
<?php 
    $cat1 = $cat;
    $args = array( 'posts_per_page' => -1, 'category' => $cat1 );?>
    $myposts = get_posts( $args );
    foreach ( $myposts as $post ) {
        $product_terms = wp_get_object_terms($post->ID, 'Brands');
        echo '<ul>';
        foreach(array_unique($product_terms) as $term) {
            echo '<li><a href="'.get_term_link($term->slug, 'Brands').'">'.$term->name.'</a></li>'; 
        }
        echo '</ul>';
    }
?>
```

but it returns duplicates for taxonomies. I tried array_unique but it doesn't work. Could you please help. Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Separate the loops, like this:

```
<?php 
    $cat1 = $cat;
    $args = array( 'posts_per_page' => -1, 'category' => $cat1 );?>
    $myposts = get_posts( $args );
    $myterms = array();
    foreach ( $myposts as $mypost ) {
        foreach ( wp_get_object_terms($mypost->ID, 'Brands') as $term ) {
            $myterms[ $term->term_id ] = $term;
        }
    }
    echo '<ul>';
    foreach( $myterms as $term ) {
        echo '<li><a href="'.get_term_link($term->slug, 'Brands').'">'.$term->name.'</a></li>'; 
    }
    echo '</ul>';
?>
```

---

If there are many terms, the approach above can result in PHP memory error. Here is another approach:

```
<?php 
    $cat1 = $cat;
    $args = array( 'posts_per_page' => -1, 'category' => $cat1 );?>
    $myposts = get_posts( $args );
    $visited_term_ids = array();
    echo '<ul>';
    foreach ( $myposts as $mypost ) {
        foreach ( wp_get_object_terms($mypost->ID, 'Brands') as $term ) {
            if ( ! isset( $visited_term_ids[ $term->term_id ] ) ) {
                echo '<li><a href="'.get_term_link($term->slug, 'Brands').'">'.$term->name.'</a></li>'; 
                $visited_term_ids[ $term->term_id ] = TRUE;
            }
        }
    }
    echo '</ul>';
?>
```

Comment: thanks frnhr for you reply. Unfortunately your suggestion doesn't work. Where Am I wrong? Thanks for your support

Comment: Exactly how it breaks (I'm not saying that I'm curtain it works, I've written the code here without testing it)?  
Put `var_dump($myterms)` after the first loop and look at the output, that should provide some clue in to what is going wrong.

Comment: There is no a specific error, simply the page doesn't show up or better I got the header then nothieng.... but after your second suggestion, I have:
array(295) { [0]=> object(stdClass)#11933 (9) { ["term_id"]=> string(3) "471" ["name"]=> string(4) "Asus" ["slug"]=> string(4) "asus" ["term_group"]=> string(1) "0" ["term_taxonomy_id"]=> string(3) "481" ["taxonomy"]=> string(6) "Marche" ["description"]=> string(0) "" ["parent"]=>

Comment: if I remove array_unique() it shows me the list of the taxonomies (Brands or Marche (in italian)) but it is still duplicated. Thanks for your help

Comment: probably these page could be useful: http://wordpress.org/support/topic/multiple-queries-compiling-into-one-loop and http://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/100216/eliminate-duplicates-in-a-foreach-loop

Comment: great! your second approach works. Thanks a lot!! Is it possibile order the taxonomy by name or smth else?

Comment: To sort them you'd have to take the first approach, and then do something like this: http://stackoverflow.com/a/4282423/236195 between the loops.