# PHP, sort array of objects and remove item by object fields

Tags: php, arrays

I seen this post [PHP, sort array of objects by object fields](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4282413/php-sort-array-of-objects-by-object-fields) and it works great for me, but I need help one step further.

Here code sample

```
 Array
(
    [0] => stdClass Object
        (
            [ID] => 1
            [name] => Mary Jane
            [count] => 420
        )

    [1] => stdClass Object
        (
            [ID] => 2
            [name] => Johnny
            [count] => 234
        )

    [2] => stdClass Object
        (
            [ID] => 3
            [name] => Kathy
            [count] => 4354
        )

   ....
```

I want to be able to remove array object that has count above 450.  How could I do this?  So basically it removes ([2] => stdClass Object) and etc.

Function I am using is this

```
function cmp($a, $b)
{
    return strcmp($a->name, $b->name);
}

usort($your_data, "cmp")
```

**So how could I go about doing this?**
Do I use the unset($text) command to do this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use [array_filter()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-filter.php) to remove items from array.

```
$arr = array( ... );
// sort array with your usort
...
// filter array to new one
$filteredArr = array_filter($arr, function($item) {
    return $item->count <= 450;
});
```

Answer (score 0):

You can't use `usort()` to remove members from the array being sorted. Your best bet would be to first use `array_filter()` to remove the objects with counts above 450, then sort the result.