# sort array of objects by variable obj property

Tags: php

I am [sorting an array of objects by object property](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4282413/php-sort-array-of-objects-by-object-fields) using this process:

```
function cmp($a, $b)
{
    return strcmp($a->name, $b->name);
}

usort($array_of_obj, "cmp"); //sorts array by object name
```

In my case, the object property is stored as in variable `$prop`, so that I can choose which property to sort from (name, date, etc). So,  I would like something like this:

```
function cmp($a, $b, $prop)  
{
    return strcmp($a->$prop, $b->$prop);
}

$prop = 'someproperty';
usort($array_of_obj, "cmp");  //sorts array by chosen object property, $prop
```

My problem here is that I cannot pass a value to the $prop argument when I call the "cmp" function. I'm not sure if I should if this is a dead end endeavor or if there is some way to work around this. What can I do?

Comment: Example #4 in the [usort documentation](http://us3.php.net/manual/en/function.usort.php) appears to do something along those lines.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could wrap the call inside an anonymous function

```
function cmp($a, $b, $prop) {
    return strcmp($a->$prop, $b->$prop);
}

$prop = 'someproperty';
usort($array_of_obj, function($a,$b) use ($prop) { 
    return cmp($a,$b,$prop); 
});
```

EDIT: [Explanation of the keyword 'use'](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1065188/in-php-5-3-0-what-is-the-function-use-identifier)

Comment: That's pretty smooth.

Answer (score 1):

You could add a static property to the  class `$a` &  `$b` belong to or a shared parent class.  You can call it something like 'sort_property', and then use that:

```
   //Set the sort property 
   Class_of_a_and_b::$sort_property = 'name';

   //call sort
   usort($array_of_obj, "cmp");

   //....stuff ...

   function cmp($a, $b)
   {
         //in real code, maybe test if the sort property is valid...
         $sort_prop = Class_of_a_and_b::$sort_property;
         return strcmp($a->$sort_prop , $b->$sort_prop );
   }
```

Of course this only works well if they're objects of the same class.

Comment: i like this idea! and I think it would work... gotta use the other one tho :)

Comment: @bsapaka yeah, the closure is far more elegant

Answer (score 0):

Just an idea

```
// ===============================================
// Start => Sort Object / Array by Key ===========
// ===============================================
function usort_array($array, $key, $order = 'asc') {
    if(strtolower($order) == 'asc')
        usort($array, function($a, $b) use ($key) { return strcmp($a[$key], $b[$key]); });
    else
        usort($array, function($a, $b) use ($key) { return strcmp($b[$key], $a[$key]); });
    return $array;
}

function usort_object($object, $key, $order = 'asc') {
    if(strtolower($order) == 'asc')
        usort($object, function($a, $b) use ($key) { return strcmp($a->$key, $b->$key); });
    else
        usort($object, function($a, $b) use ($key) { return strcmp($b->$key, $a->$key); });
    return $object;
}
// ===============================================
// End => Sort Object / Array by Key =============
// ===============================================
```