# Sort array with objects on property of objects

Tags: php, arrays, sorting, object, numbers

I would like to sort an array of objects by a property of the specific object. This is my array with objects:

[image]

As you can see I have an array `$all_studies` with **2 objects**. How can I now sort on the `graduationYear` property of the objects? So I would like to have  an array with objects and the the order with object 2010 first, then 2014, ... (in this case the order is already correct but this won't always be the same ..).

This is what I've tried but with no succes:

```
$all_studies = usort($all_studies, "sort_objects_by_graduationyear");

function sort_objects_by_graduationyear($a, $b) {
    if((int)$a->graduationYear == (int)$b->graduationYear){ return 0 ; }
    return ($a->graduationYear < $b->graduationYear) ? -1 : 1;
}
```

But I just get `true` back. I've never used the usort function so I don't really know how to work with it. Can someone help me?

Comment: see [link](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4282413/sort-array-of-objects-by-object-fields)

Comment: `usort` sorts in place, it does not *return* the result. See the examples in [the manual](http://php.net/usort).

Comment: what if I wanna chan ge the order, from bigger to lees, what can I change in ur function for make it work, thansk?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The function **usort** returns "true" on success. So, good news :).

If you want to check if the sort is done, you only have to check your $all_studies object after the usort.

```
$status = usort($all_studies, "sort_objects_by_graduationyear");
print_r($all_studies);
```

Answer (score 2):

You were assigning the value of `usort` to `$all_studies` which'll be `true` and `false` thus you were not getting the value as desired. In fact you need to just `sort` the array and `print` that values and its all done

Try as

```
usort($all_studies, "sort_objects_by_graduationyear");

function sort_objects_by_graduationyear($a, $b) {
    if((int)$a->graduationYear == (int)$b->graduationYear){ return 0 ; }
    return ($a->graduationYear < $b->graduationYear) ? -1 : 1;
}

print_r($all_studies);
```

> Return Values ¶
>
> Returns TRUE on success or FALSE on failure.

[Check Docs](http://php.net/usort)