# How to sort an array in alphabetical order using codeigniter

Tags: php, arrays, codeigniter, sorting

How to sort an array in alphabetical order using codeigniter

```
array(
     Array(

            [id] => 4
            [business_category] => Air_conditioning-Auto
            [business_name] => test business
        );
      Array(

            [id] => 55
            [business_category] => Air_conditioning-Auto
            [business_name] => asdf
        );
);
```

Comment: Am use my code in the controller in codeigniter

Comment: Please update question with whole `array` which you want to sort, even `object` is fine.

Comment: If you're getting this array from query you can simply sort it within your query only

Answer (score 0):

Answer taken from this post:
[Sort array of objects by object fields](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4282413/sort-array-of-objects-by-object-fields)

Use [usort](http://php.net/manual/en/function.usort.php), here's an example adapted from the manual:

```
function cmp($a, $b)
{
    return strcmp($a->name, $b->name);
}

usort($your_data, "cmp");
```

---

If you're sorting the array from inside the class and your sorting function `cmp` is also defined inside the class, then use this:

```
usort($your_data, array($this, "cmp"))
```

Comment: Can you please quote the error here, so I can help you further