# Organise Array output alphabetically

Tags: php, arrays, foreach

I've tried multiple ways without success, is there anyway I can organise the below so the result is alphabetical?

```
<?php
    $datas = array_slice($facilities, 0, $leftoshownumber);
    foreach($datas as $data) {
        if(in_array ($data->Name,$removedouble)) continue; 
        echo '<div class="checkmark-33"><div class="fa-stack fa-1x checkmark-icon"><i class="fa fa-circle fa-stack-2x icon-background"></i><i class="fa fa-check fa-stack-1x icon-text"></i></div><div class="checkmark-inner">'. $data->Name .'</div></div>'; 
    }; 
?>
```

Any help would be great, Thanks!

Comment: You're not really showing any output but what you need to do is sort `$datas` before looping though it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your code, `$datas` is an **array of objects**, with each individual `$data` object containing a "Name" field. So you need to sort the `$datas` array alphabetically based on the value of each `$data->Name` field. As explained in the question [Sort array of objects by object fields](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4282413/sort-array-of-objects-by-object-fields), this can be done with [usort](http://php.net/manual/en/function.usort.php):

```
<?php
    function cmp($a, $b) {
        return strcmp($a->Name, $b->Name);
    }

    $datas = array_slice($facilities, 0, $leftoshownumber);
    usort($datas, "cmp");

    foreach($datas as $data) {
        if(in_array ($data->Name,$removedouble)) continue; 
            echo '<div class="checkmark-33"><div class="fa-stack fa-1x checkmark-icon"><i class="fa fa-circle fa-stack-2x icon-background"></i><i class="fa fa-check fa-stack-1x icon-text"></i></div><div class="checkmark-inner">'. $data->Name .'</div></div>'; 
    }; 
?>
```

Answer (score 0):

You could use a user defined sort, [usort](http://php.net/manual/en/function.usort.php):

```
<?php 
    function cmp($a, $b){ // User defined sorting algorithm
        if ($a == $b)
            return 0;
        return ($a['name'] < $b['name']) ? -1 : 1;
    }
    $datas = array_slice($facilities, 0, $leftoshownumber);
    usort($datas, "cmp"); // use the function cmp() to do sorting comparison 
    foreach($datas as $data) {
        if(in_array ($data->Name,$removedouble)) continue; 
            echo '<div class="checkmark-33"><div class="fa-stack fa-1x checkmark-icon"><i class="fa fa-circle fa-stack-2x icon-background"></i><i class="fa fa-check fa-stack-1x icon-text"></i></div><div class="checkmark-inner">'. $data->Name .'</div></div>'; 
    }; 

?>
```

Comment: This doesn't load anything for me?