# Wordpress: Default sorting by column of custom post type

Tags: wordpress, sorting

I have a custom post type called Contact, with custom fields like first name, surname, telephone number etc.

In the admin section they're sorted chronologically I think, but I need them to be sorted by surname by default.

I've read all the other solutions on here and none of them work, including:

```
function set_post_order_in_admin( $wp_query ) {
global $pagenow;
  if ( is_admin() && 'edit.php' == $pagenow && !isset($_GET['orderby'])) {
    $wp_query->set( 'orderby', 'surname' );
    $wp_query->set( 'order', 'ASC' );
  }
}
add_filter('pre_get_posts', 'set_post_order_in_admin' );
```

But whatever field I try to sort by, nothing changes, except toggling ASC/DESC seems to change to reverse chronological ordering.

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Same thing is happening to me as well.

Comment: your if conditions are wrong. First try to do this after removing the ifs.

Answer (score 10):

Refer below solutions,

```
function wpa84258_admin_posts_sort_last_name( $query ){
    global $pagenow;
    if( is_admin()
        && 'edit.php' == $pagenow
        && !isset( $_GET['orderby'] )
        && !isset( $_GET['post_type'] ) ){
            $query->set( 'meta_key', 'last_name' );
            $query->set( 'orderby', 'meta_value' );
            $query->set( 'order', 'ASC' );
    }
}
add_action( 'pre_get_posts', 'wpa84258_admin_posts_sort_last_name' );
```

OR refer this [solution](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/45/how-to-sort-the-admin-area-of-a-wordpress-custom-post-type-by-a-custom-field)

Comment: This worked. I missed this before but thanks God I tried it now.

Comment: For a custom post type, replace `!isset( $_GET['post_type'] )` by `@$_GET['post_type'] == 'my_custom_type'` (or something alike)

Comment: And to sort by `menu_order` (which is a _post attribute_ rather than a _meta_), get rid of the `'meta_key'` line and use `$query->set( 'orderby', 'menu_order' );`.

Answer (score 5):

Replace

```
 $wp_query->set( 'orderby', 'surname' );
 $wp_query->set( 'order', 'ASC' );
```

With

```
$query->set( 'meta_key', 'surname' ); // name of your post meta key
$query->set( 'orderby',  'meta_value'); // meta_value since it is a string
```

It may help

Comment: @Junaid take a look at https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/194572/how-do-i-set-the-default-admin-sort-order-for-a-custom-post-type-to-a-custom-col

Answer (score 0):

I am a drupal developer and haven't got a chance to play with WordPress. 
We had the same problem and this is how we fixed it.

Get your custom content type data (either WP default api or custom query), it would be an array of objects. Sort them using below function. return sorted array of posts. Not sure, in which hook you need to implement this in wordpress.

```
/**
 *  Function to sort array by key
 *  sortArrayByKey($yourArray,"name",true); //String sort (ascending order)
 *  sortArrayByKey($yourArray,"name",true,false); //String sort (descending order)
 *  sortArrayByKey($yourArray,"id"); //number sort (ascending order)
 *  sortArrayByKey($yourArray,"count",false,false); //number sort (descending order)
 */

function sortArrayByKey(&$array, $key, $string = false, $asc = true)
{
    if ($string) {
        usort($array, function ($a, $b) use (&$key, &$asc) {
            if ($asc) return strcmp(strtolower($a{$key}), strtolower($b{$key}));
            else        return strcmp(strtolower($b{$key}), strtolower($a{$key}));
        });
    } else {
        usort($array, function ($a, $b) use (&$key, &$asc) {
            if ($a[$key] == $b{$key}) {
                return 0;
            }
            if ($asc) return ($a{$key} < $b{$key}) ? -1 : 1;
            else     return ($a{$key} > $b{$key}) ? -1 : 1;

        });
    }
}
```

and then in your hook, you can call this function by

```
 return $this->sortArrayByKey($posts, "surname");
```

Function copied from this answer:   https://stackoverflow.com/a/39872303/3086531

Answer (score -1):

This snippet sets the **'Name' column as the default sorting order (ascending) for Woocommerce Products**

```
function sort_woocommerce_products_by_name( $query ){
    global $pagenow;
    if( is_admin()
        && 'edit.php' == $pagenow
        && isset($_GET['post_type']) && $_GET['post_type']=='product'
        && !isset( $_GET['orderby'] ) ){
            $query->set( 'orderby', 'title' );
            $query->set( 'order', 'asc' );
    }
}
add_action( 'pre_get_posts', 'sort_woocommerce_products_by_name' );
```

Comment: although your code works, it does not answer the question