# Sort Arrays by selected key

Tags: php, arrays

I got following array:

```
[
 [0] => ["value" => "somevalue", "sort_number" => 3],
 [1] => ["value" => "somevalue", "sort_number" => 1],
 [2] => ["value" => "somevalue", "sort_number" => 2],
]
```

I want to sort the 3 arrays inside the outer one by `sort_number`.

I already tried to play around with the `array_multisort()` function (http://php.net/manual/de/function.array-multisort.php) but somehow i can`t get it to work with it. The examples shown in the documentation also look different to what i have here.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Sort array of objects by object fields](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4282413/sort-array-of-objects-by-object-fields)

Comment: @RobbyCornelissen I will check this a bit later. So sorry if this is a duplicate, haven`t seen this thread before. Thank you.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

with `array_multisort`:

```
$arr = [
 ["value" => "somevalue1", "sort_number" => 3],
 ["value" => "somevalue2", "sort_number" => 1],
 ["value" => "somevalue3", "sort_number" => 2],
];

array_multisort(array_column($arr, "sort_number"), $arr);

print_r($arr);
```

Answer (score 1):

Here is solution suitable for `PHP7`:

```
$myArray = [
    0 => ["value" => "somevalue", "sort_number" => 3],
    1 => ["value" => "somevalue", "sort_number" => 1],
    2 => ["value" => "somevalue", "sort_number" => 2],
];

usort($myArray, function($a, $b) {
    return $a['sort_number'] <=> $b['sort_number'];
});

print_r($myArray);
```

Solution for older versions:

```
function multisort($a, $b) {
    return $a["sort_number"] - $b["sort_number"];
}
usort($myArray, "multisort");
```

**Ouput:**

```
Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [value] => somevalue
            [sort_number] => 1
        )

    [1] => Array
        (
            [value] => somevalue
            [sort_number] => 2
        )

    [2] => Array
        (
            [value] => somevalue
            [sort_number] => 3
        )

)
```

Comment: Thanks for you answer. Bad the project is not running PHP 7 yet.

Comment: @Marcel Wasilewski Edited for older versions. Try it please and let me know.