# how to sort a json object in laravel

Tags: php, json, laravel, laravel-5

i have the following response, how to sort it depending on the distnace

```
{
  "Message": "Done.",
  "Status": true,
  "InnerData": [
      {
         "id": 66,
         "name": "tito",
         "distance": 74,
      },
      {
         "id": 67,
         "name": "liver pool",
         "distance": 83
      },
      {
         "id": 67,
         "name": "Text",
         "distance": 72
      }
  ]
}
```

i tried the usort but i didn't make it.
i also tried this answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4282413/sort-array-of-objects-by-object-fields) but it seems to be different than the one i need

Comment: you can sort it in sql. But in your situation just use foreach loops and sort it manual.

Comment: You need to decode the JSON into a PHP data structure, sort it, then re-encode it. Post what you've tried and we can help you debug it.

Comment: the distance parameter is not a sql field, i calculate it and pass it in the response.
can you please give me an example how to sort it using foreach ?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1597736/how-to-sort-an-array-of-associative-arrays-by-value-of-a-given-key-in-php

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In pure PHP 7

```
<?php

$json = '{
  "Message": "Done.",
  "Status": true,
  "InnerData": [
      {
         "id": 66,
         "name": "tito",
         "distance": 74
      },
      {
         "id": 67,
         "name": "liver pool",
         "distance": 83
      },
      {
         "id": 67,
         "name": "Text",
         "distance": 72
      }
  ]
}';
$array = json_decode($json, true);
usort($array['InnerData'], function($a, $b) {
    return $a['distance'] <=> $b['distance'];
});

print_r($array);
```

Comment: This is great ! Could you also perform additional checks for `id` and `name` as `usort()` doesn't guarantee a stable sort for order of equal elements. 

In this context, the OP might want to preserve the order.

Answer (score 3):

As @hdifen suggested, if you're using Laravel it's a breeze to do this.

```
$json = '{
  "Message": "Done.",
  "Status": true,
  "InnerData": [
      {
         "id": 66,
         "name": "tito",
         "distance": 74
      },
      {
         "id": 67,
         "name": "liver pool",
         "distance": 83
      },
      {
         "id": 67,
         "name": "Text",
         "distance": 72
      }
  ]
}';

$data = json_decode($json, true);

$data['InnerData'] = collect($data['InnerData'])->sortBy('distance', SORT_REGULAR, true);

$encoded = json_encode($data);

echo $encoded;
```

Output:

```
{  
   "Message":"Done.",
   "Status":true,
   "InnerData":{  
      "1":{  
         "id":67,
         "name":"liver pool",
         "distance":83
      },
      "0":{  
         "id":66,
         "name":"tito",
         "distance":74
      },
      "2":{  
         "id":67,
         "name":"Text",
         "distance":72
      }
   }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Json is mainly used as a common format for sending data.

In Laravel you can convert a json object to a php array easily by using json_decode().

```
$phpArray = json_decode($json);
```

From here you can convert it to a collection to take advantage of laravels collection functions.

```
$laravelArray = collect($phpArray);
```

After this take a look at https://laravel.com/docs/5.5/collections to do sort/filter or do whatever you want to the array.