# How to filter and set priority arrays based on key in php

Tags: php, arrays, codeigniter, sorting, laravel-5

```
Array
(
    [0] => stdClass Object
        (
            [category_id] => 5
            [distributor_id] => 999999
            [name] => Attractions
            [parent_category_id] => 0
            [is_global_category] => 0
            [category_logo] => qrcodes/categoryupload/img_1438954822_attractions.png
            [is_active] => 1
            [ticket_ids] => 
            [position] => 0
        )

    [1] => stdClass Object
        (
            [category_id] => 5
            [distributor_id] => 8885
            [name] => Attractions
            [parent_category_id] => 0
            [is_global_category] => 0
            [category_logo] => qrcodes/categoryupload/img_1438954822_attractions.png
            [is_active] => 1
            [ticket_ids] => 
            [position] => 0
        )

    [2] => stdClass Object
        (
            [category_id] => 6
            [distributor_id] => 999999
            [name] => Walk & Bike
            [parent_category_id] => 0
            [is_global_category] => 0
            [category_logo] => qrcodes/categoryupload/img_1438406863_walk-bike.png
            [is_active] => 1
            [ticket_ids] => ["13594"]
            [position] => 0
        )

)
```

i want to create new array from this array.Here two type of distributor id can come one is :

**[distributor_id] => 999999 this is fixed**

second is

**[distributor_id] => $cod_id(8885) any person who is login**

Now i want to create new array and want to give priority to [distributor_id] => $cod_id(8885) and want result look like this

```
Array
    (

        [0] => stdClass Object
            (
                [category_id] => 5
                [distributor_id] => 8885
                [name] => Attractions
                [parent_category_id] => 0
                [is_global_category] => 0
                [category_logo] => qrcodes/categoryupload/img_1438954822_attractions.png
                [is_active] => 1
                [ticket_ids] => 
                [position] => 0
            )

        [1] => stdClass Object
            (
                [category_id] => 6
                [distributor_id] => 999999
                [name] => Walk & Bike
                [parent_category_id] => 0
                [is_global_category] => 0
                [category_logo] => qrcodes/categoryupload/img_1438406863_walk-bike.png
                [is_active] => 1
                [ticket_ids] => ["13594"]
                [position] => 0
            )

    )
```

How to handle it using foreach and other solution

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Sort array of objects by object fields](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4282413/sort-array-of-objects-by-object-fields)

Comment: @Dum  it's ot fullfill my requirment

Comment: What have you tried? Where are you stuck?

Answer (score 0):

I've written a possible solution for your issue, comments are mentioned wherever necessary, see if it helps you.
Suppose,

```
Array
(
    [0] => stdClass Object
        (
            [category_id] => 5
            [distributor_id] => 999999
            [name] => Attractions
            [parent_category_id] => 0
            [is_global_category] => 0
            [category_logo] => qrcodes/categoryupload/img_1438954822_attractions.png
            [is_active] => 1
            [ticket_ids] => 
            [position] => 0
        )

    [1] => stdClass Object
        (
            [category_id] => 5
            [distributor_id] => 8885
            [name] => Attractions
            [parent_category_id] => 0
            [is_global_category] => 0
            [category_logo] => qrcodes/categoryupload/img_1438954822_attractions.png
            [is_active] => 1
            [ticket_ids] => 
            [position] => 0
        )

    [2] => stdClass Object
        (
            [category_id] => 6
            [distributor_id] => 999999
            [name] => Walk & Bike
            [parent_category_id] => 0
            [is_global_category] => 0
            [category_logo] => qrcodes/categoryupload/img_1438406863_walk-bike.png
            [is_active] => 1
            [ticket_ids] => ["13594"]
            [position] => 0
        )
```

is stored in a variable named `$your_array`, then

```
$existArr = array(); // we'll be storing data in category_id => distributor_id pair
$newArr   = array(); // this will be the new array

foreach($your_array as $your_arr){ // traverse the data(old array)

    if(array_key_exists($your_arr->category_id, $existArr)){ // check if key already exists

        if($existArr[$your_arr->category_id] == 8885){ // if the key exists, check if the value of that key is 8885(priority)

            continue; // if yes, skip

        }else{ // if not, over-write(update the value) 

            $existArr[$your_arr->category_id] = $your_arr->distributor_id; // or simply 8885 -- update the {$existArr}

            foreach($newArr as $key => $val){ // search the key of previous saved value in {$newArr}

                if($your_arr->category_id == $val->category_id){ 

                    $newArr[$key] = $your_arr; // update the current value in {$newArr}
                    break;

                }
            }

        }

    }else{ // if the key doesn't exist

        $existArr[$your_arr->category_id] = $your_arr->distributor_id; // or simply 8885 -- insert key => value in the {$existArr}
        $newArr = $your_arr; // insert the current value in {$newArr}

    }

}
print_r($newArr);
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use [usort()](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.usort.php) function.

```
function comparator($object1, $object2) { 
    return $object1->distributor_id > $object2->distributor_id; 
} 

usort($array, 'comparator');
```

Read more from [here](https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/sort-array-of-objects-by-object-fields-in-php/amp/).