# How to sort Google Generated Keyword Ideas Result?

Tags: php, google-ads-api

Although, I have successfully implemented Google Keyword Planner API to generate Keyword Ideas in PHP with the link below.

https://developers.google.com/google-ads/api/docs/keyword-planning/generate-keyword-ideas

Does anyone know the fastest way to sort the result by AvgMonthlySearches?

```
// Iterate over the results and print its detail.
foreach ($response->iterateAllElements() as $result) {
    /** @var GenerateKeywordIdeaResult $result */
    // Note that the competition printed below is enum value.
    // For example, a value of 2 will be returned when the competition is 'LOW'.
    // A mapping of enum names to values can be found at KeywordPlanCompetitionLevel.php.
    printf(
        "Keyword idea text '%s' has %d average monthly searches and competition as %d.%s",
        $result->getText(),
        is_null($result->getKeywordIdeaMetrics()) ?
            0 : $result->getKeywordIdeaMetrics()->getAvgMonthlySearches(),
        is_null($result->getKeywordIdeaMetrics()) ?
            0 : $result->getKeywordIdeaMetrics()->getCompetition(),
        PHP_EOL
    );
}
```

Thanks

Comment: For best performance, you should sort your results directly in the query. See the `ORDER BY` clause in https://developers.google.com/google-ads/api/docs/reporting/example#php

Answer (score 0):

You could implement a function that can compare two instances of your object and use [usort](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.usort.php):

```php
function cmp($a, $b) {
    return $a->getKeywordIdeaMetrics()->getAvgMonthlySearches() - $b->getKeywordIdeaMetrics()->getAvgMonthlySearches();
}

$list = iterator_to_array($response->->iterateAllElements());

usort($list, "cmp");

// $list will be your sorted array to work with from here onwards ...
```

See more:

- [Sort array of objects by object fields](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4282413/sort-array-of-objects-by-object-fields)
- https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.iterator-to-array.php

Comment: Thanks for your prompt reply.

I've placed you snipped before iteration like this:

function cmp($a, $b) {
    return $a->getKeywordIdeaMetrics()->getAvgMonthlySearches() - $b->getKeywordIdeaMetrics()->getAvgMonthlySearches();
}

usort($response, "cmp");

foreach ($response->iterateAllElements() as $result) {
....

and I got a warning saying:

Warning: usort() expects parameter 1 to be array, object given in /Applications/MAMP/htdocs

As I expected the response variable from API was an array isn't it?

Please help and thank you.

Comment: @webmastx You should verify what the response is by dumping the variable. Then you'll see instance of which class it is and you can find documentation for it.

Comment: You are dealing with an iterator and will need to convert to an array with `iterator_to_array` to be able to use `usort`. I updated the code of the answer if you want to try it. Be advised that this won't give you the best performance though.