# PHP sort array by specific key

Tags: php, arrays, sorting

I have an array that looks like this:

```
"lines":[
 {"value":1,"id":0},
 {"value":10,"id":1}
]
```

My goal is to always get the one with value: 10 as first so I want to sort it with ksort maybe but I am not sure

This is my goal:

```
"lines":[
 {"value":10,"id":1},
 {"value":1,"id":0}
]
```

Anyone who can help many thanks!

Comment: Did you ever try to search before posting? There are dozens of similar questions available in SO

Comment: @Thamilan Yes I did but I can't find anything to sort on a specific key or put an elemt at the front of an array

Comment: Did you try these http://stackoverflow.com/a/4022355/5447994 ? http://stackoverflow.com/a/2804735/5447994 ?

Comment: @Thamilan Yes but looks very complicated

Comment: Complicated or not @FrankLucas - those answers are going to solve your issue. In fact, looking at that first one, it's not really that complicated. [Look at the PHP.net docs for usort](http://php.net/manual/en/function.usort.php) and you should be able to figure it out if you actually have a go. Then, if you're stuck come back with your code and we can help.

Answer (score 0):

> @Frank Lucas If you want to order a multidimensional array by any
>   key so you can you usort() function

If you want to sort you array by "value" index in descending order so try the below code and understand it

```
<?php
    $lines = array(array("value"=>1,"id"=>0), array("value"=>10,"id"=>1));
    function order($a, $b){
        if ($a["value"] == $b["value"]) {  //here pass your index name
            return 0;
        }
        return ($a["value"] > $b["value"]) ? -1 : 1;    // this your key "value" will be in descending order as  requirement
        //but if you want to change this order from descending to Ascending order so just change the -1 and 1 place in above condition 
    }
    usort($lines,"order");
    print_r($lines);
?>
```

It will solve your problem (y)