# Sort multi-dimensional array so specific sub-array is first

Tags: php, arrays, sorting

I want to sort an array so that a specific array with a specific value is shown as the first in the array.

The array I have:

```
array = [
        [0] => [
            'id' => 123,
            'name' => 'Random'
        ],
        [1] => [
            'id' => 156,
            'name' => 'keyboard'
        ],
        [2] => [
            'id' => 12235,
            'name' => 'Text'
        ],
    ];
```

I want the sub-array where the name is '**keyboard**' to be the first in line of the big array.

Does anyone have suggestions?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Sort multi-dimensional array by specific key](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4022289/sort-multi-dimensional-array-by-specific-key)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[usort](http://php.net/manual/en/function.usort.php) Sort an array by values using a user-defined comparison function

```
$array = [
    0 => [
        'id' => 123,
        'name' => 'Random'
    ],
    1 => [
        'id' => 156,
        'name' => 'keyboard'
    ],
    2 => [
        'id' => 12235,
        'name' => 'Text'
    ],
];

usort($array, function ($item) {
    return  $item['name'] != 'keyboard';
});

print_r($array);
```

See the [demo](https://implode.io/rPq9eL)

Answer (score -1):

```
$myArray = [
    [0] => [
        'id' => 123,
        'name' => 'Random'
    ],
    [1] => [
        'id' => 156,
        'name' => 'keyboard'
    ],
    [2] => [
        'id' => 12235,
        'name' => 'Text'
    ],
];

$temp = $myArray[0];
$myArray[0] = $myArray[1];
$myArray[1] = $temp;
```

Comment: always add an explanation to avoid the generation of the copy-and-paste developer^^ :)