# Order array by date in PHP?

Tags: php

I am trying to order an array by its date. I have tried to do this using usort but it will not change the order of the array in any way?

I am trying to show oldest near the start, and newest near the bottom.

```
usort($history, function($a, $b) {
    return strtotime($a['date']) < strtotime($b['date']) ? 1 : -1;
});
```

Array structure:

```
array:3 [
    0 => array:3 [
        "date" => "13/02/2020",
        "event" => "validate",
        "note" => "",
    ]

    1 => array:3 [
        "date" => "02/02/2020",
        "event" => "created",
        "note" => "",
    ]

    2 => array:3 [
        "date" => "03/04/2020",
        "event" => "approved",
        "note" => "",
    ]
]
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Sort multi-dimensional array by specific key](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4022289/sort-multi-dimensional-array-by-specific-key)

Comment: `DD/MM/YYYY` is not a [valid date format](https://www.php.net/manual/en/datetime.formats.date.php) in PHP. Use `MM/DD/YYYY` or `YYYY-MM-DD`

Comment: Have you tried checking what `strtotime` returns for your dates? You'd be better off using `DateTime`.

Comment: BTW If this data came from a database it would be a lot easier to order it in the SQL query