# How to sort an array in array by a specific key in PHP

Tags: php, arrays

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Sorting an associative array in PHP](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/777597/sorting-an-associative-array-in-php)
>   [How to sort a multidimensional array by a certain key?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2804690/how-to-sort-a-multidimensional-array-by-a-certain-key)

I would like to know how can I sort an array in array by a specific key.

For example:

```
$array = array( 0 => array("id"=>25), 1 => array("id"=>15) , 2 => array("id"=>19) );
```

now I want to sort the array by the key "id", i'm expecting this result:

```
$array = array( 0 => array("id"=>15), 1 => array("id"=>19) , 2 => array("id"=>25) );
```

Anybody can help ?

Thanks

Comment: A similar question has already been posed and answered: [Sorting an associative array in PHP](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/777597/sorting-an-associative-array-in-php). Please use the search function next time. See the [FAQ](http://stackoverflow.com/faq).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Hope this may work.

```
function cmp($a, $b){
    return $a['id'] - $b['id'];
}
usort($array, 'cmp');
```

Comment: Why -1 me? This is working actually.  T.T

Comment: the answer to the question is to link the duplicate and vote for close. Probably because of that.

Comment: @hakre oh, sorry I didn't see it :)