# Sort an array by key value

Tags: php, arrays, sorting

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How to sort a multidimensional array by a certain key?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2804690/how-to-sort-a-multidimensional-array-by-a-certain-key)

I would like to sort an array, which looks like below, by the key value:

```
 $arr = ([0]=>Int(5)
         [1]=> Array ( [0]=>Int(4) , [1]=>String(10) , [2]=>String(22) , ['prop']=>Int(2))
         [2]=> Array ( [0]=>Int(4) , [1]=>String(10) , [2]=>String(22) , ['prop']=>Int(2))
         [3]=> Array ( [0]=>Int(4) , [1]=>String(10) , [2]=>String(22) , ['prop']=>Int(2))
        )
```

So, as a result i would like to have the $arr sorted by the ['prop']'s value.

I've tried bubble sort but without any result.

Comment: Take a look at [usort()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.usort.php)

Comment: use the search function before asking questions please.

Comment: @Jeroen i've tried usort() and it goes on timeout on execution!

Answer (score 0):

```
usort($array, function($a, $b) {
    if($a['prop'] == $b['prop']) return 0;
    return ($a['prop'] < $b['prop']) ? -1 : 1;
});
```

Note: this only works if you have PHP >5.3 (because it uses [an anonymous function](http://php.net/manual/en/functions.anonymous.php))

Comment: i've tried usort() and it goes on timeout on execution!