# how sort this type of associate array by "department_id"

Tags: sorting

```
Array
(
    [0] => stdClass Object
        (
            [id] => 16
            [department_id] => 4
            [employee_status] => 1


        )

    [1] => stdClass Object
        (
            [id] => 17
            [department_id] => 8
            [employee_status] => 1
        )

)
```

Comment: Which language are you trying to implement this in ?

Comment: In addition to @NomanUrRehman, What have you tried so far?

Comment: @NomanUrRehman in php

Comment: Possible duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2804690/how-to-sort-a-multidimensional-array-by-a-certain-key

Comment: @noman-ur-rehman this link sort array of multidimensional array but my aaray contain stdClass Object

Comment: @noman-ur-rehman i post the solution of this type of array

Answer (score 2, accepted):

i found a solution that sort object array

```
function cmp($a, $b) {
     return $b->department_id - $a->department_id;
}
$sirtedArray=usort($employeelist, "cmp");
```