# PHP code to sort an array.....?

Tags: php, arrays, sorting, multidimensional-array

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Sorting an associative array in PHP](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/777597/sorting-an-associative-array-in-php)

Hello all,

I have an array like

```
<?php
    $data[] = array('id' => 67, 'hits' => 2);
    $data[] = array('id' => 86, 'hits' => 1);
    $data[] = array('id' => 85, 'hits' => 6);
    $data[] = array('id' => 98, 'hits' => 2);
    $data[] = array('id' => 89, 'hits' => 6);
    $data[] = array('id' => 65, 'hits' => 7);
 ?>
```

And I want to `sort` this array on the basis on `hits`.

Please suggest some code that help me....

Thanks in advance

Comment: Why do you ask a question that is copy-pasted from the [PHP docs](http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-multisort.php) (Example #3) *and* already has a solution?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[Sorting an associative array in PHP](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/777597/sorting-an-associative-array-in-php)

Answer (score 2):

You need the usort() function - allows you to specify a custom compare function. See http://php.net/manual/en/function.usort.php.

Your compare function could for example be
function cmp($a, $b)
{
    return strcasecmp($a['edition'], $b['edition']);
}

Answer (score 1):

[`usort()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.usort.php) with the following comparison function:

```
function cmpHits($a, $b) {
    return $a['hits'] - $b['hits'];
}
```

(Untested, [`uasort()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.uasort.php) if you want to maintain key associations.)

Answer (score -1):

Try this:

```
array_multi_sort($data, array('edition'=>SORT_DESC));

function array_multi_sort($array, $cols)
{
    $colarr = array();
    foreach($cols as $col => $order)
    {
        $colarr[$col] = array();
        foreach ($array as $k => $row)
        {
            $colarr[$col]['_'.$k] = strtolower($row[$col]);
        }
    }

    $eval = 'array_multisort(';
    foreach($cols as $col => $order)
    {
        $eval .= '$colarr[\''.$col.'\'],'.$order.',';
    }
    $eval = substr($eval,0,-1).');';
    eval($eval);
    $ret = array();
    foreach($colarr as $col => $arr)
    {
        foreach($arr as $k => $v)
        {
            $k = substr($k,1);
            if (!isset($ret[$k])) $ret[$k] = $array[$k];
            $ret[$k][$col] = $array[$k][$col];
        }
    }
    return $ret;
}
```

Resource: http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-multisort.php

Comment: Using eval is not (and should never be) necessary!