# Understanding array sorting or comparison function callbacks using user-defined functions

Tags: php, arrays

Pretend like I have no idea what I'm doing, which I don't.  Can you explain how the array sorting and comparison functions which require callbacks work?

Take the `uasort()` function for example.  How am I supposed to design a callback function to work with this?  What is the meaning of "-1", "+1", and "0" when I'm trying to sort data?  Will it scan through all array elements?  Or is it more efficient than that?  What if I want "w" to come before "b", while "a" comes before "x"?  Any advice you can give in this seemingly simple area will be most appreciated.

Comment: This is similar and may help. Not sure if it's specific enough for you. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8456029/how-does-usort-work

Answer (score 1):

I'll give it a shot!

For an example, let's take a list of names. You and I both know how to sort a list of names alphabetically, and done it a hundred bazillion times. Same thing applies to, say, numbers. Computers need to be able to sort data where the sorting may not be so intuitive.

Callback functions for sorting arrays involve the idea of allowing the array to contain an arbitrary kind of data, with the callback supplying the "rules" for saying how any two items in that array relate to each other. In this way, a sorting algorithm can take that array of data, call the "callback" function repeatedly to determine which elements belong in which order, and return the sorted list. That's the very essence of a callback.

If you want a literal analogy, pretend you hand a list of data to a friend, and they only know a *method* for sorting, but don't know how the items in your list relate. They "call back" to you, asking the question "Which of these two elements comes first?" And you, knowing the data, and the rule, take the items, apply your rules, and then tell the friend the answer. Ultimately, after repeating this process multiple times, your data returns to you sorted.

In this way, a "callback" that returns -1, 0, or 1, returns a value that says, when called with two pieces of data, -1 says "item one precedes item two," 0 says "item one equals item two," and +1 says "item one follows item two." You simply supply the comparisons that determine which value is returned based on the rules for your data.  You can define an arbitrary set of data and define whatever precedence rule you wish within your problem "space." As an aside, that's an important part of object-oriented programming - I can leverage this "callback" idea to implement a *generic* version of a complex sorting algorithm and *never know or care* about the *kind* of data being sorted - all because the programmer using this "canned" sorting mechanism will provide the "logical plumbing" the sort routine needs.

I think that's a decent shot at an explanation, and all in a language-agnostic way, too! :) Hope that helps.

**Edit.** Let me provide an example:

```
List:

Item #  Value
1        12
2        15
3         9
4        26
5         4
```

if I set out to find the smallest item in the list, I'd start with item 1, and compare it against each remaining item in the list. So, first pass, I'd compare Item 1 to Item 2:

```
compare(item(1),item(2))
```

which would return -1, because the value of 12 *precedes* 15. Now, I go to the *next* item in the list:

```
compare(item(1),item(3))
```

which this time returns 1, because 12 *follows* 9, meaning item(3) is now the smallest item found so far. Now, we compare thusly:

```
compare(item(3),item(4))
```

In this case, compare return -1, because 9 precedes 26, leading us to the final compare:

```
compare(item(3),item(5))
```

And this call will return +1, because 9 comes after 4. As we've exhausted all items in the list, we know item(3) is the smallest item. We'd then swap that item for the "previously" top item, and repeat the entire process starting at item(2). This is an example of a notoriously inefficient "bubble sort," but works for the purposes of this illustration. That's where the "first item" and "second item" references come from. Sorting, regardless of language, and like any other problem in computer science, boils down to breaking down big problem in to small bites, and sorting boils down to repeatedly comparing two items from a larger list.

Answer (score 0):

First, read the manual. The [summary page](http://www.php.net/manual/en/array.sorting.php) is a good place to see the variety of sorts specified. To answer some of your questions:

Of course the sort scans all array elements. How else would it know where the last element might be placed? But that's not really relevant. You don't need to understand which sort algorithm is used. You only need to provide a function that knows how to compare any two items in the array, *without respect to any other of the items*.

The sort algorithm does its magic, calling your function whenever it wants to know which element "comes before" the other. It calls your function with two items, each as a parameter.

Your function returns:

- -1 (or any number less than zero) if the first item is less than the second item.
- 0 if they are equal
- 1 (or any number greater than zero) if the first item is greater than the second item.

You can write a method to do any type of sort. If you want 'w' to come before 'b' then you'd want to return -1 if the first parameter starts with 'w' and the second parameter starts with 'b'. It's too contrived of an example for me to bother writing a sample function.

But before you can learn how to write a callback, you first need to actually have a reason to sort so that you have a goal to accomplish.

Run this example to see how many times the sort function calls your callback:

```
<?php

function mysort($a, $b)
{
  echo "$a vs $b\n";

  return $a - $b;
}

// randomly create an array with 1 to 20 as elements
$data = range(1,20);
shuffle($data);    

// before
print_r($data);

// sort
usort($data, 'mysort');

// after   
print_r($data);
```

It systematically sorts the array using the sort algorithm by using the information your function tells it about how to order two individual items.

Comment: "*without respect to any other of the items*"  This is the part I'm having trouble with.  Take a whole array containing 20 elements as an example.  When stepping from one element to the next during the entire sort operation, what does "-1", "+1", "0" mean?

Comment: You're not writing the sort algorithm. You are only telling the sorter how to compare two items. The sorter asks, "Does A come before or after B, or are they the same?" It just keeps asking over and over again (in a sensible fashion per the algorithm) until it has figured out the order. It might be comparing the first element with the second or the fifth, etc, at any given time it calls your function. Your function doesn't need to know or care about that.

Comment: @bob-the-destroyer Sounds like what you're really asking is how [quicksort](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Quicksort) works, as I believe this is the sorting algorithm PHP employs behind the array sorting functions.

Comment: Bare with me here.  To help me understand, what is the "first item", and what is the "second item".  And, how do additional array elements step in here?

Comment: When a sorting algorithm starts doing its work, eventually it will start comparing items in your list. Take the simple case of finding the "largest" number in a list. You'll take the first number, and compare it against each number in the list until you find a larger one. The "top" number is the first item, and the "top+1" item is the "second" item, and the process repeats with "top" and "top+2", and so on..

Comment: I'm sorry you guys.  I appreciate you trying.  But I'm still not understanding what PHP does with the return values -1, 1, 0 on callback functions.  By any chance, do you have the line in PHP sourcecoude where something like this is handled?

Comment: @bob-the-destroyer, run the example I've added to the post to help you visualize that the sort calls your function many many times. As Wiseguy has stated, PHP uses the quick sort. If you want to know *why* PHP calls your function in that order, read the Wikipedia article. Reading the PHP source code won't help you.

Comment: @bob-the-destroyer, I tried to update my answer above with a non-language-specific, step-by-step illustration of how the "compare" notion works, and why the -1,0,1 values are returned in the midst of a sort. I hope this helps clear through the fog!

Comment: I don't know why, but this alone seems _the_ most complex feature of PHP that I've ever come across personally.  All the rest is easy.  Give me a bit to absorb and test this.