# Sort alphabetically multi dimensional array by a sub value

Tags: php

```
$arr=array(
    [0]=>array(
        [username]=>bsmith
        [name]=>Bob Smith
    )
    [1]=>array(
        [username]=>mjohnson
        [name]=>Mike Johnson
    )
    [2]=>array(
        [username]=>ameyer
        [name]=>Meyer Adam
    )
)
```

Need to natural (alphabetical) sort by a specific sub-value of the array.

If sort by "username" => => ameyer, bsmith, mjohnson

```
$arr=array(
    [0]=>array(
        [username]=>ameyer
        [name]=>Meyer Adam
    )
    [1]=>array(
        [username]=>bsmith
        [name]=>Bob Smith
    )
    [2]=>array(
        [username]=>mjohnson
        [name]=>Mike Johnson
    )

)
```

If sort by "name" => bsmith, ameyer, mjohnson

```
$arr=array(
    [0]=>array(
        [username]=>bsmith
        [name]=>Bob Smith
    )
    [1]=>array(
        [username]=>ameyer
        [name]=>Meyer Adam
    )
    [2]=>array(
        [username]=>mjohnson
        [name]=>Mike Johnson
    )
)
```

What is the most elegant way to do that?

Should I use uasort?

Comment: possible duplicate of [How do I sort a multidimensional array in php](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/96759/how-do-i-sort-a-multidimensional-array-in-php)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You will need to use `usort`, which will both be the easiest and fastest method. You can just use the result code of `strcmp` to determine the alpha sort order.

```
function sortByUsername($a, $b) {
  return strcmp($a['username'], $b['username']);
}

usort($arr, sortByUsername);
```

Comment: how uasort is working? what is $a and $b in this particular case?

Comment: `uasort` calls `sortByUsername` with the two elements to compare. That said, I much prefer JimiDini's solution, it is much more flexable.

Comment: there is no need to use uasort. usort is enough, as the top-level array is not associative. Also  see my answer for generic solution

Comment: @ihtus php engine will send pairs of various elements from your array there until it gets enough eveidence of how sorted array should look like

Comment: so first time it sends pairs 0 and 1; then 1 ad 2?

Comment: @ihtus something like that, yes. you can do experiment by adding logger to the sorter function :)

Comment: @ihtus there's an elegant practical answer below. if you're interested in theoretical part of this, take a look here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12208364/understanding-array-sorting-or-comparison-function-callbacks-using-user-defined?lq=1

Comment: guys, how alphabetical sort is achieved using strcmp by comparing which string is longer or shorter?

Comment: `strcmp` does not compare string length.

Comment: manual: Returns < 0 if str1 is less than str2; > 0 if str1 is greater than str2, and 0 if they are equal.

Comment: @ihtus "less" doesn't mean shorter :) it does lexicographic comparision. see https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lexicographical_order

Comment: less then = less then alphabetically, not length. ie: 'a' is less then 'b'.

Comment: http://www.tuxradar.com/practicalphp/4/7/15 It takes two words for its two parameters, and returns -1 if word one comes alphabetically before word two, 1 if word one comes alphabetically after word two, or 0 if word one and word two are the same.

Comment: We know this.. why post it here?

Comment: for anyone who does not know, like me :)

Answer (score 2):

```
$sorter = function($key) {
    return function($data, $data2) use ($key) {
        return strcmp($data[$key], $data2[$key]);
    };
};

usort($arr, $sorter('username'));
var_dump($arr);

usort($arr, $sorter('name'));
var_dump($arr);
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use [`array_multisort`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-multisort.php):

```
foreach ($arr as $array) {
    $names[] = $array['name'];
}

array_multisort($names,SORT_STRING,$arr);
print_r($arr);
```