# understanding the ternary operator in php

Tags: php, arrays

I was hoping someone could explain to me what the ? -1 : 1; mean in the below ternary operator? Many thanks

```
<?php
 $people = array(
 array( "name" => "hank", "age" => 39 ),
 array( "name" => "Sarah", "age" => 36 ),
 );
 usort( $people, function( $personA, $personB ) {
 return ( $personA["age"] < $personB["age"] ) ? -1 : 1;
 } );

 print_r( $people );
```

Comment: True and false is my first guess..

Comment: You know the name of the construct and the functions involved in this code and never ever looked up what they mean or do? Hint: http://php.net

Answer (score 1):

Ternary operator logic is the process of using `(condition) ? (true return value) : (false return value)` statements to shorten your `if/else` structures.

So in your case `if/else` will be like below code:

```
if($personA["age"] < $personB["age"]) {
   return  -1 ;
}
else{ 
   return 1;
}
```

for more detail have alook at: http://php.net/manual/en/language.operators.comparison.php#language.operators.comparison.ternary

In the case of `usort` function it will return -1 to indicate that the value in `$personA['age']` is less than the one in `$personB['age']`.
for more detail have a look at [how does usort work?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8456029/how-does-usort-work) and http://php.net/manual/en/function.usort.php

**Update 1**

The callback in `usort` provided to the sorting functions in PHP have three return values:

```
0:  both elements are the same
-1 (<0): the first element is smaller than the second
1 (>0):  the first element is greater
```

Now, `usort` probably uses some kind of quicksort or mergesort internally. For each comparison it calls your callback with two elements and then decides if it needs to swap them or not.

Answer (score 1):

Ternary operator is a short hand for `if else`.

Ternary operator makes code shorter and cleaner.

Basic syntax for ternary operator is:

```
[assignment variable] = (condition) ? [if condition is true] : [if condition is false]
```

If `if` and `else` also has only one statement, then you can use ternary operator.

For example:

```
if (TRUE) {
 $a = 1;
}
else {
 $a = 0;
}
```

Can be simply written as:

```
$a = (TRUE) ? 1 : 0;
```

Answer (score 1):

It's just shorthand IF, ELSE essentially, can be really handy

```
$name = "Jack";

if($name == "Jack")
    echo "You are Jack";
else 
    echo "You are not Jack";
```

VS

```
echo ($name == "Jack") ? "You are Jack" : "You are not Jack";
```

I belive in php you can call functions if the condition is/isn't met, so in this example if $ok is true, we run the pass function else fail function.

```
($ok) ? pass() : fail();
```