# PHP simple game to found out which player should be won

Tags: php

in this structure of league table that's a simple game in `PHP`, we want to tracks the score of each player in league, we pass and define each score for player with this code:

```php
$table->save_result('Albert', 2); //albert with 2 score
$table->save_result('Albert', 3);//albert with 3 score
```

here there are some tip:

the player's rank in the league is calculated using the following logic:

1. 1- the player with the highest score is ranked first(rank 1). the player with the lowest score is ranked last.
2. 2- if two players are tied on score, then the player who has played
   the fewest games is ranked higher.

base class that save player with scores:

```php
class Table
{
    private $standings = [];

    public function __construct(array $players)
    {
        $this->data = [];
        foreach($players as $key => $p) {
            $this->data[$p] = [
                'key'        => $key,
                'games_played' => 0,
                'player_score'        => 0
            ];
        }
    }

    public function save_result(string $player, int $score)
    {
        $this->data[$player]['games_played']++;
        $this->data[$player]['player_score'] += $score;
    }
}
```

now we have 2 player which score of them are the same, for example:

```php
$table->save_result('Pele', 5);
$table->save_result('Zidane', 5);
```

now if two players are tied on score, then the player who has played, then the player who was first in the list of players in ranked higher.

however `Pele` and `Zidane` have played fewer games than Mike and as `Zidane` is before `Pele` in the list of players, he is ranked first. therefore.the correct result should `Zidane`, for example:

```php
$table = new Table(array('Albert', 'Pele', 'Zidane'));

$table->save_result('Albert', 2); //albert with 2 score
$table->save_result('Albert', 3);//albert with 3 score
$table->save_result('Pele', 5);
$table->save_result('Zidane', 5);
echo $table->get_rank_result(1);
```

how can we calculate this score in this below function? i can't do it

```php
public function get_rank_result(int $rank) : string
{
   // should be return 'Zidane';
}
```

Comment: If this for continuous stream or it is having a defined set of data already?

Comment: @nice_dev should be having  a defined set of data

Comment: Then you can simply use `usort()`

Comment: @nice_dev can you help me how can i use that?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [In php how does usort() function works](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8456029/in-php-how-does-usort-function-works)

Answer (score 0):

This can be done very easy with [array_multisort()](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.array-multisort.php), because we can make the order dependent. But to do so, we need to create a new data structure, because associative keys are not changed, only indices.

Since 'key' in your structure keeps the order added and the name key of `$this->data`, we can get the name back.

```
public function get_rank_result(int $rank) : string
{
    $data = [
        array_column($this->data, 'player_score'),
        array_column($this->data, 'games_played'),
        array_column($this->data, 'key'),
    ];

    array_multisort(
        $data[0], SORT_DESC, SORT_NUMERIC,
        $data[1], SORT_ASC, SORT_NUMERIC,
        $data[2], SORT_DESC, SORT_NUMERIC,
    );

    return array_keys($this->data)[array_search($data[2][$rank - 1], array_column($this->data, 'key'))];
}
```

```
echo $table->get_rank_result(1);
```

> Zidane