# PHP - Sorting a multidimensional array

Tags: php, arrays, sorting

```
Array
(
    [data] => Array
        (
            [0] => Array
                (
                    [name] => Nicki Escudero
                    [id] => 27700035
                )

            [1] => Array
                (
                    [name] => Yorgo Nestoridis
                    [id] => 504571368
                )
         )
)
```

How can I sort this multidimensional array using its name?

I tried with `array_multisort` but it's not working.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Sorting an associative array in PHP](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/777597/sorting-an-associative-array-in-php)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want to use `array_multisort`, you would use the following:

```
$array = array(
    'data' => array(
        array(
            'name' => 'Yorgo Nestoridis',
            'id'   => 504571368,
        ),  
        array(
            'name' => 'Nicki Escudero',
            'id'   => 27700035,
        ),  
    ),  
);  

$names = array();
foreach($array['data'] as $datum) {
    $names[] = $datum['name'];
}   

array_multisort($names, SORT_ASC, $array['data']);
var_dump($array); // now sorted by name
```

The other choice is to use a custom comparison function:

```
function compareNames($a, $b) {
    return strcmp($a['name'], $b['name']);
}   

usort($array['data'], 'compareNames');
```

Answer (score 0):

It is already sorted :-) What do you want to sort by? And where is the data coming from? if you get it from a DB you should sort differently.

Comment: i am converting from json to array.

Comment: And what is the source of the JSON? Can you not change the sorting before the JSON is generated? More efficient..

Comment: This is not an answer, it's comment.

Comment: Why is it not an answer? If he can sort this out in a more efficient way than he is currently doing, it is definitely an answer. TS didn't provide much info.

Answer (score 0):

If those are the only two values you have, you can try making `id` the index of the array and the name can be the value. You can then use `asort` to sort the array by name and maintain the index-value relation.

By making `id` the index, I mean `$array[27700035]` would return `Nicki Escudero`.

```
// Copy the array to a new array.
foreach($array as $val) {
    $newArray[$val['id']] = $val['name'];
}

asort($newArray);
```

Edit: I've gone through the manual and you can also use `usort` with a custom comparison function. Although I've never used this and can be of very little help... [PHP usort](http://php.net/manual/en/function.usort.php)