# Sort hours in PHP

Tags: php, xml

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How do I sort a multidimensional array in php](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/96759/how-do-i-sort-a-multidimensional-array-in-php)
>   [Sorting an associative array in PHP](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/777597/sorting-an-associative-array-in-php)

I have an array of hours, titles and descriptions, but the hours are disordered (12:00, 04:15, 18:30, 10:20...)

This is my PHP code:

```
$content = simplexml_load_file( $sampleXML );
foreach( $content->item as $item ) {

    echo $item->hour;
    echo $item->title;
    echo $item->description;    
}
```

and this is a sample of the XML:

```
<item>
    <hour>12:00</hour>
    <title>Sample Title 1</title>
    <description>Sample Description 1</description>
</item>

<item>
    <hour>04:15</hour>
    <title>Sample Title 1</title>
    <description>Sample Description 1</description>
</item>

<item>
    <hour>18:30</hour>
    <title>Sample Title 1</title>
    <description>Sample Description 1</description>
</item>
```

I need to sort the hours with it's corresponding title and description. How can I do this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This should work for 24 hour format like in your example:

```
usort($a, create_function('$a, $b', 'return strcmp($a->hour, $b->hour);'));
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use [usort()](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.usort.php) and pass it a function that would know how to compare two of the XML nodes using the time to order them.