# PHP Sort associative array based on array values

Tags: php, multidimensional-array, sorting

I currently have an associative array of values that I need sorted based on values in another array.

Example:

If I have an array of values,
AssocArray = '122'=>'12', '123'=>'32', '232'=>'54', '343'=>'12'

I need to check it against another array of values,
orderArray = '232', '123'

if it exists then push the value to the top of the AssocArray. so the final array looks like this.

AssocArray = '232'=>'54', '123'=>'32', '122'=>'12', '343'=>'12'

Sorry I do not have any working code, I am still learning PHP.

Any help would be really grateful :) Thank you.

Comment: Look here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/777597/sorting-an-associative-array-in-php

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Loop through your `$orderArray`, and check if an element with that key is present in `$AssocArray`. If it is, add that element to the `$result` array, and remove it from the original `$AssocArray`. Then, you just have to merge the remaining elements in `$AssocArray` with whatever was pushed to the top of the `$results` array:

```
$AssocArray = array( '122'=>'12', '123'=>'32', '232'=>'54', '343'=>'12');
$orderArray = array( '232', '123');

rsort( $orderArray, SORT_STRING); // Make sure the order array is sorted from highest to lowest

$result = array();
foreach( $orderArray as $key) {
    if( isset( $AssocArray[ $key ])) {
        $result[$key] = $AssocArray[ $key ];
        unset( $AssocArray[ $key ]);
    }
}

foreach( $AssocArray as $k => $v) {
    $result[$k] = $v;
}

print_r( $result); // Print the resulting array
```

You can see that [this prints](http://viper-7.com/3ORfyw):

```
Array
(
    [232] => 54
    [123] => 32
    [122] => 12
    [343] => 12
)
```

Answer (score 0):

```
$orderArray = array("232", "123");

function customSort($key1, $key2){
    $key1Pos = array_search($key1, $orderArray);
    $key2Pos = array_search($key2, $orderArray);
    if($key1Pos !== NULL && $key2Pos != NULL){
        return $key1Pos - $key2Pos;
    }else if($key1Pos === NULL){
        return 1;
    }else{
        return -1;
    }
}


uksort($array, "customSort");
```