# sorting date associative array

Tags: php

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Sorting an associative array in PHP](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/777597/sorting-an-associative-array-in-php)

I have this array

```
array
  0 => 
    array
      'start_date' => string '2012-11-14' (length=10)
      'end_date' => string '2012-11-19' (length=10)
  1 => 
    array
      'start_date' => string '1980-10-10' (length=10)
      'end_date' => string '1980-10-10' (length=10)
  2 => 
    array
      'start_date' => string '2012-11-20' (length=10)
      'end_date' => string '2099-10-10' (length=10)
```

I want to sort it on start_date. I dont think sort() method works on it. Any idea?

Comment: http://php.net/manual/en/function.usort.php

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use [`usort`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.usort.php) :

#### PHP 5.3+

```
usort($array, function($a, $b) {
   //return strtotime($a['start_date']) - strtotime($b['start_date']);
   return strcmp($a['start_date'], $b['start_date']);
});
```

#### Older versions of PHP

```
function startDateCmp($a, $b) {
   //return strtotime($a['start_date']) - strtotime($b['start_date']);
   return strcmp($a['start_date']), $b['start_date']);
}

usort($array, 'startDateCmp');
```

Comment: Actually, anonymous functions was introduced with php 5.3

Comment: in this particular case, strtotime is overkill. the dates are already in a string format that can be sorted directly. but otherwise yes, you'd have to convert to a timestamp before comparing.

Comment: @MarcB, I like to play safe, but you're right :)

Comment: @MarcB Assuming certain dates are formatted "2012-05-01" and not "2012-5-1", you're right.

Answer (score 1):

Use `usort` and supply your own function to do the ordering.

```
function cmp($a, $b)
{
    return $b['start_date'], $a['start_date'];
}

usort($array, "cmp");
```