# Recursively sorting a JSON array

Tags: php, arrays, json, sorting, usort

I've looked a little and found an answer that partially does what I am interested in doing, see:  [Sorting a JSON array in PHP](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13942547/sorting-a-json-array-in-alphabetical-order-in-php)

I have some decoded JSON that looks like this, just a sample.

```
{
    "status": "OK",
    "page": {
        "rows": 5000,
        "more": 0,
        "number": 1
    },
    "accounts": [
        {
            "connected": 0,
            "settings": {
                "link_first_study_only": "0",
                "update_study_source_on_notify": "1",
                "link_external_whitelist": "",
                "other_ingress_tags": ""
            },
            "must_approve_upload": 0,
            "css": null,
            "share_via_gateway": 0,
            "password_expire": 90,
            "vanity": "medpics"

        }
    ]
}
```

What I would like to do is sort everything alphabetically so that it is easier to read and uniform.  So that what I would see is:

```
{
    "accounts": [
        {
            "css": null,
            "connected": 0,
            "must_approve_upload": 0,
            "password_expire": 90,
            "settings": {

                "link_external_whitelist": "",
                "link_first_study_only": "0",
                "other_ingress_tags": "",
                "update_study_source_on_notify": "1"
            },

            "share_via_gateway": 0,
            "vanity": "medpics"
        }
    ],
    "page": {
        "more": 0,
        "number": 1,
        "rows": 5000,
    }
    "status": "OK"
}
```

Every element is sorted alphabetically.  Is that possible ?

Comment: there is no array, only objects

Comment: @LarsStegelitz In PHP they would be associative arrays.

Comment: Write a recursive function that uses `ksort()`. It will need to take the array argument as a reference parameter.

Comment: Why isn't the `settings` array sorted alphabetically in your desired result?

Comment: JSON is a data exchange format, not for people to casually read. What purpose would the complex recursive algorithm to do this solve other than vanity?

Comment: Sorry, I edited the desired result.  Also, it really is for vanity and development.  I want to easily look at the responses that I get and have the elements always in the same order.  It isn't that way by default.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Pretty straightforward

```
$json = <<<JSON
{
    "status": "OK",
    "page": {
        "rows": 5000,
        "more": 0,
        "number": 1
    },
    "accounts": [
        {
            "connected": 0,
            "settings": {
                "link_first_study_only": "0",
                "update_study_source_on_notify": "1",
                "link_external_whitelist": "",
                "other_ingress_tags": ""
            },
            "must_approve_upload": 0,
            "css": null,
            "share_via_gateway": 0,
            "password_expire": 90,
            "vanity": "medpics"

        }
    ]
}
JSON;

$json = json_decode($json, true);

function ksort_recursive(&$array) {
    ksort($array);
    foreach ($array as &$value) {
        if (is_array($value)) {
            ksort_recursive($value);
        }
    }
}

ksort_recursive($json);

print_r($json);
```

Proof of solution here

https://3v4l.org/qUAA0

Comment: That will work.  It is a kind of vanity and development thing, but it makes it really easy to visually compare records for responses that have the same structure but different data.  Thanks.