# Sorting Associative Array by Date

Tags: php, arrays, sorting

I have this king of array in php and would like to sort it by the date Array[i][2] of the array.. the highest date should be at the top.. how can i do this?

this is my array:

```
Array ( 
    [0] => Array ( 
        [0] => 15.04.2013 
        [1] => 17:34 
        [2] => 06.04.2013 
        ) 

    [1] => Array ( 
        [0] => 15.04.2013 
        [1] => 15:12 
        [2] => 13.04.2013 
    ) 

    [2] => Array ( 
        [0] => 15.04.2013 
        [1] => 16:42 
        [2] => 16.02.2013 
    ) 

    [3] => Array ( 
        [0] => 04.04.2013 
        [1] => 21:12 
        [2] => 16.03.2013 
    ) 

    [4] => Array ( 
        [0] => 29.04.2013 
        [1] => 17:16 
        [2] => 19.04.2013 
    ) 
)
```

Comment: This question has the answer. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/777597/sorting-an-associative-array-in-php

Comment: already tried to use usort, but it get's sorted wrong

Comment: @IlendemliMuhammet Have you tried usort like the example i provided below?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can make use of [usort](http://php.net/manual/en/function.usort.php)

Example:

```
usort($array,function ($a,$b){
    $t1 = strtotime($a[0]);
    $t2 = strtotime($b[0]);
    if ($t1 == $t2) {
        return 0;
    }
    return ($t1 < $t2) ? -1 : 1;
});
```

Comment: how is the usage of this? how do you call the function?

Comment: @IlendemliMuhammet wrap that whole thing in a function of your own name. then you can call it whenever you want with whatever you want.

Comment: it is making use of usort, passing the array, then an anonymous function.

Comment: awesome seems to be working! :)

Comment: @IlendemliMuhammet accept his answer so he gets the upvote points.

Comment: i had to wait two minutes ^^

Answer (score 0):

You can do it using [`usort()`](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.usort.php) , like this:

```
function cmp($a,$b) {
   if ($a[2] == $b[2]) {
      return 0;
   }
   $arr = explode('.',$a[2]);
   $brr = explode('.',$b[2]);
   $anum = (int) ($arr[2] . $arr[1] . $arr[0]);
   $bnum = (int) ($brr[2] . $brr[1] . $brr[0]);
   return ($anum < $bnum) ? -1 : 1;
}

usort($array, "cmp");
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
function cmp($a, $b)
{
    $a = strtotime($a[2]);
    $b = strtotime($b[2]);
    if ($a == $b) {
        return 0;
    }
    return ($a < $b) ? -1 : 1;
}

$a = array ( 
    0 => array ( 
        0 => '15.04.2013' 
        ,1 => '17:34'
        ,2 => '06.04.2013' 
        ) 

    ,1 => array ( 
        0 => '15.04.2013' 
        ,1 => '15:12' 
        ,2 => '13.04.2013' 
    ) 

    ,2 => array ( 
        0 => '15.04.2013' 
        ,1 => '16:42' 
        ,2 => '16.02.2013' 
    ) 

    ,3 => array ( 
        0 => '04.04.2013' 
        ,1 => '21:12' 
        ,2 => '16.03.2013' 
    ) 

) ;

usort($a, "cmp");
```

Comment: did the exactly same thing with ibu's code

Answer (score -1):

you can write your custom sorter callback by using [usort](http://php.net/manual/en/function.usort.php) (like in lbu's answer)

[array_multisort](http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-multisort.php)  is the alternative, using like;

here is a sorter function for multi dimmensional arrays

https://gist.github.com/tufanbarisyildirim/1220785

Comment: The php manual would be a better starting point http://php.net/manual/en/function.usort.php