# How can I sort row records in php page?

Tags: php

I have a table on a php page where "Offical_gene_Symbol" column I need to sort "Assending". here is the php block for that particular column.

```
if($test['test_type_id'] == 1 || $test['test_type_id'] == 5) {
    $gene_ids = FetchGenesByPanelTest($test['id']);
    $genes = array();
    foreach($gene_ids  as $gi){
        $genes[] = FetchGene($gi);      
    }
    <table>
                <tr>
                    <th>Offical Gene Symbol</th>
                    <th style="width:200px;">OMIM Id</th>
                </tr>
                <?php foreach($genes as $gene): ?>
                <tr>
                    <td><a href="/gene-detail.php?id=<?= $gene['id']; ?>&iframe=true&width=790&height=600" rel="prettyPhoto" title="<?= htmlentities($gene['offical_gene_symbol']); ?>"><?= $gene['offical_gene_symbol']; ?></a></td>
                    <td><a href="http://omim.org/entry/<?= $gene['omim_id']; ?>" target="_blank"><?= $gene['omim_id']; ?></a></td>
                </tr>
                <?php endforeach; ?>
                </table>
```

Could you please help how can I do that in this code? Thanks in Advance. Updated code.

Comment: Where is the array $genes coming from?

Comment: I think array $genes come from here: if($test['test_type_id'] == 1 || $test['test_type_id'] == 5) {
 $gene_ids = FetchGenesByPanelTest($test['id']);
 $genes = array();
 foreach($gene_ids  as $gi){
  $genes[] = FetchGene($gi);  
 }

Comment: please update your code with your comment

Comment: I updated my code above.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Sorting an associative array in PHP](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/777597/sorting-an-associative-array-in-php)

Answer (score 3):

Since `$genes` seems to be a multidimensional array and i suppose you want it sorted by the title ('offical_gene_symbol') i suggest you to use the [usort](https://www.php.net/usort) function that will provide you a way to create a custom comparation algorithm.
As for the comparation, php offers you different comparing method for two strings:

- [strcasecmp](https://www.php.net/strcasecmp) Binary safe case-insensitive string comparison,Returns < 0 if str1 is less than str2; > 0 if str1 is
  greater than str2, and 0 if they are equal.
- [strcmp](https://www.php.net/strcmp) Binary safe string comparison (case sensitive). works as
  the above function.

In php 5.3+ you can perform the sorting this way:

```
usort($genes, function($a, $b) {
    return strcasecmp($a['offical_gene_symbol'],$b['offical_gene_symbol']);
});

foreach($genes as $gene) {
...
}
```

In php < 5.3 you have to use a callable function :

```
function cmp($a, $b)
{
    return strcasecmp($a['offical_gene_symbol'],$b['offical_gene_symbol']);
}
    usort($genes, 'cmp');
    
    foreach($genes as $gene) {
    ...
    }
```

Comment: Maybe add some more details about strcasecmp or a link. I will delete my answer i guess since yours is more accurate.

Answer (score 0):

A straightforward use of [PHP sort() function](http://php.net/sort). Isn't it?

Answer (score 0):

If this is a PHP array please check this functions, make sure to go check the other sort functions at php [docs](http://www.php.net/manual/en/array.sorting.php)

```
$array = array(
    array('Offical_gene_Symbol' => 'v'),
    array('Offical_gene_Symbol' => 't'),
    array('Offical_gene_Symbol' => 'a'),
    array('Offical_gene_Symbol' => 'c'),
    array('Offical_gene_Symbol' => 'd')
    );
```

## sort

```
sort($array);
echo debug($array);
```

Output

```
array(5) (
    0 => array(1) (
        "Offical_gene_Symbol" => string(1) "a"
    )
    1 => array(1) (
        "Offical_gene_Symbol" => string(1) "c"
    )
    2 => array(1) (
        "Offical_gene_Symbol" => string(1) "d"
    )
    3 => array(1) (
        "Offical_gene_Symbol" => string(1) "t"
    )
    4 => array(1) (
        "Offical_gene_Symbol" => string(1) "v"
    )
)
```

## rsort

```
rsort($array);
print_r($array);
```

Output

```
array(5) (
    0 => array(1) (
        "Offical_gene_Symbol" => string(1) "v"
    )
    1 => array(1) (
        "Offical_gene_Symbol" => string(1) "t"
    )
    2 => array(1) (
        "Offical_gene_Symbol" => string(1) "d"
    )
    3 => array(1) (
        "Offical_gene_Symbol" => string(1) "c"
    )
    4 => array(1) (
        "Offical_gene_Symbol" => string(1) "a"
    )
)
```

Answer (score -1):

You can sort the array before you echo it to the page.

Something like:

```
</tr>
<?php
sort($genes);
foreach($genes as $gene):
?>
<tr>
```

Which will give you the values in ascending order by the value.

Edit: Changed asort to sort.

Comment: This works for few but not all. Like gene with A,B,C,N,D,A. Initially gene list was like N,D,Z,A,C,G,. Thanks for the tips. Could you please give me something else. Thanks.

Comment: You can try it with just sort perhaps. Can you provide more information on the array $genes? Is it a has/associative array or just an array? Do you want to sort by the values or the keys?

Comment: sort and asort both has same result. Thanks.

Comment: actually array $genes come from if($test['test_type_id'] == 1 || $test['test_type_id'] == 5) {
 $gene_ids = FetchGenesByPanelTest($test['id']);
 $genes = array();
 foreach($gene_ids  as $gi){
  $genes[] = FetchGene($gi);  
 }

Comment: @Kortoa: Check the two other Answers mentioning usort. There is one by me and one that is even better by kawashita86. If those do not work for you, you might want to add more detail to your question/goal.